# Reviewing process for tags you're unfamiliar with

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, review-queues

Not sure if this has been asked already, but while reviewing the "Close Votes" and "Low Quality" queues I usually find myself in a situation when I just can't tell if the question is low quality/too broad or unclear simply because it's not from my tag and I don't trust my judgment (so I just skip them).

The problem is that many times I see a very basic and clear enough questions being closed by users from other tags with some ridiculous reason like "Too Broad", simply because they aren't familiar with the tag and thus their judgment is flawed. The biggest problem with a question like that is that it is reasonably hard to gather 4 other people to reopen it.

Take [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27850054/count-a-character-object-by-row-in-a-large-data-frame/) simple [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) question with a reproducible example and clear desired output (explained in words). **All** five users who closed it aren't from [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) and basically have no idea what they are doing.

So the question is: should the reviewing process (in this aspect) be reconsidered? I'm well aware that it is very important to retain a critical mass of reviewers in order to keep improving the content of this site, but can't we really try to restrict the queues to some more "qualified" users per each tag?

**Alternative suggestion would be**: Let users with a gold badge in a specific tag to be able to reopen questions with a single vote (similar to the ability to close dupes).

Comment: I'm sure there are duplicates to enhancing gold-badger power over *just* wielding the mighty mjölnir.

Comment: _"Let users with a gold badge in a specific tag to be able to reopen questions with a single vote"_ That already works fine.

Comment: It works "fine" only for dupes.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `r` knowledge, other than the fact that the `r` community has a greater tolerance for `sendmetehcodez` questions than the rest of the community does.

Comment: IMHO it is a pretty bad question, it doesn't show any effort and basically asks others to do the work for him; it doesn't require any r knowledge to make the decision this would need to be closed as 'too broad' or 'off topic "why isn't this code working"', or maybe even 'unclear what you are asking'.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: If the answer is a one-liner, you can't really argue that the OP should have put in more effort. Writing an awful for-loop would not have provided any helpful information at all. It's a bad question, but it's very specific, clear and perfectly on topic.

Comment: @shadow: So you're saying the wrong close reason was used?

Comment: In the [SO Close Vote Reviewers](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room we are happy to close stuff but are also willing to help in re-opening questions if there is reasonable doubt about its closure. If you have a question that we need to look at, drop a message and some of the regulars will try to help you out.

Comment: How can anyone be so judgmental as to state *"...basically have no idea what they are doing"*. If you are willing to provide a solution to a question that shows no research effort or code attempts, that's your prerogative. However it doesn't mean the rest of the community will think the same based on basic site guidelines

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I would say the question should not have been closed, though perhaps it deserved some downvotes for "show me teh codez"; IIRC that's not actually a valid close reason *by itself*.

Comment: @artlessnoise I didn't notice that tag.

Comment: @RobertHarvey shadow said that he thinks that this question is *very specific, clear and perfectly on topic*... I guess he meant that it shouldn't be closed at all?

Comment: @rene that's a good suggestion, I''ll keep it in mind.

Comment: @charlietfl, if the question shows no research effort, even if providing a reproducible example & desired output, it should be closed as "too broad"?

Comment: @DavidArenburg are you suggesting that someone who simply shows some data is creating a reproducible *problem*? I've never even used R but I bet I could google up at least a start point for some code. Spoon feeding help vampires , or letting new users think that being a help vampire is acceptable isn't beneficial to those individuals in the long run now is it?

Comment: Shows no research is not a close reason. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283177/is-too-broad-a-valid-reason-to-close-a-question-that-doesnt-show-any-research?cb=1

Answer (score 6):

If reviewers are unfamiliar with a subject, they would do best to skip reviewing. It is unfortunate that the review badges encourage people to make judgements even if they aren't the ones best suited to do so, and sometimes the easiest thing to do is to follow the crowd and pile on close votes.

Perhaps we could allow people to get credit for the Close Votes review even if they skip it. Perhaps we could justify that by asking them why they're skipping it (the Question is borderline good/bad, they don't feel qualified to decide, etc...) and provide another hoop to jump through, like a request to make a comment asking for improvement if apropos. Maybe they can have a bank of creditable skips, but they won't get the credit twice in a row, and they only get 3 credits a day.

Things that could have improved the situation, at least in this case, would have been to edit out the superfluous material (the thanks and preface) and at least capitalize the first word of the first sentence. There were also *no* comments on the question. When I see a deserving question in the close-votes queue, I try to comment contradicting the proposed reason for closing if I think it is wrong, and specifically state why. There were no comments on it.

For all of these reasons and the reasons stated in the comments on this meta question, I can see why the original question was closed. However, the system did work: the question was reopened.

I'm quite confident, however, that if the asker asked with best practices (instead of: disclaiming ability, offering thanks in advance, and not giving a sample code of what they were trying) this question would not have been so borderline.

Perhaps we could come up with a minor linter of some sort to provide feedback as the question is being composed. It could say things like:

> - It looks like you're disclaiming your ability. Please don't. Everyone starts somewhere, but the most important part of getting a good answer for
>     your question is to demonstrate where you are on the path to finding
>     an answer by showing what you've already tried.
> - You don't have any code blocks, showing what you've tried is likely to get you more help faster - what have you tried so far?
> - You're using a code block, but you don't seem to have any code, be sure to show what you've tried so far.
> - It looks like you're signing off or thanking in advance, while that may seem polite, answerers actually would prefer you to not clutter up
>     your question with those kinds of statements. Keeping it to just the facts is the best way to be polite on StackOverflow.

I think if StackExchange did this, then the overall quality of the questions, at least at the low end, would improve.

Comment: regarding review badges discouraging skip, see [Additional requirement for Steward or Reviewer badge to help new reviewers learn about using “Skip”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232052/165773) at MSE

Comment: The "system worked" because I've posted this on meta, who knows how long it would take to reopen it otherwise. Also, while I do agree about encouraging "skip" and with your suggested feedback, I'm certainly don't agree that this question should have been closed in the first place. Moreover, (from personal experience) I insist that people from unfamiliar to them tags, should be restricted in moderating power - if not completely stripped of it.