# Is "too broad" a valid reason to close a question that doesn't show any research effort?

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons, needs-more-focus

For example, [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27885020/4279) may have [a well defined solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885020/find-all-possible-substrings-in-a-string-in-python#comment44171718_27885020). Is it correct to [close it as "too broad"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885020/find-all-possible-substrings-in-a-string-in-python?#comment44171867_27885020):

> Because op failed to show the attempts and the answerer need to write
>   all the code for him. A mod told me like that.

Could a mod stand up and explain it?

Comment: "I need to find the substrings in such a way that blah blah" -- similar questions at Code Golf may easily have tens answers, so too broad for SO may apply (not suggesting that it's good fit for [CG](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as it has no winning criterion, and likely would be voted down there for being boring)

Comment: @gnat: *any* valid Code Golf question may easily have tens answers. Anyway, the question is posted on StackOverflow, not Code Golf. The code that answers the question is a one-liner. wtf is it "too broad"?! Could somebody show me a dictionary that interprets "too broad" that way? "WAR IS PEACE," "FREEDOM IS SLAVERY," "IGNORANCE IS STRENGTH."

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Read the part *"too many possible answers"*. This question could also be closed as off-topic: *"asking to recommend or find a tutorial"*.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå: I don't see *"too many possible answers"* compared to other SO questions. Most questions may have multiple answers. Look at [the most voted Python question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?sort=votes&pageSize=50) -- **all** of them have more than one answer. I don't see anything in the "powerset" question that suggests that it has *"too many possible answers"*.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian You're referring to questions asked 6-7 years ago when questions like **[What's your favorite “programmer” cartoon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon)** were allowed. Time has changed, so has the community and its rules.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå: what specific questions ([among 50 I've linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?sort=votes&pageSize=50)) are not valid SO questions (using the current SO rules)? You can exclude these questions (if you've managed to find them). The point still stands. Most SO questions may have multiple answers. There is *nothing* special about  the "powerset" one.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Look at the second question: [What is a metaclass in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python). Ask this question today and it will be down-voted to oblivion (no research effort) and closed as *"too broad"*.

Comment: [What IDE to use for Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/81584/1699210) would be closed immediately today and is standing since it's (historical?) locked.

Comment: I don't consider *"What is a metaclass in Python?"* to be "too broad". I know Python, I can answer it. Do you? *What IDE to use for Python?* might be off-topic by today standards. OK `1` question from `50` can't be used as a justification today. 25 to go (I'll wait).

Comment: Anyhow, that original question is probably a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306654/finding-all-possible-permutations-of-a-given-string-in-python

Comment: It's not broad at all. The whole point of Q&A sites is to help others by providing quality answers. If the _quality_ of the question is not so good, edit it. Id it's beyond repair, delete it. I think you people have forgotten why this site exists. If it's a duplicate, merge what you can and delete one of them. Why do you have to make things so difficult? This isn't rocket science.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk: **wrong**.  A power set and permutations and  are different things. It is clear from the example input/output even if you don't know Python. I don't understand how you could confuse it: `['',
 'a',
 'b',
 'c',
 'd',
 'ab',
 'ac',
 'ad',
 'bc',
 'bd',
 'cd',
 'abc',
 'abd',
 'acd',
 'bcd',
 'abcd']` vs. `['abcd', 'abdc', 'acbd', 'acdb', 'adbc', 'adcb', 'bacd', 'badc', 'bcad', 'bcda', 'bdac', 'bdca', 'cabd', 'cadb', 'cbad', 'cbda', 'cdab', 'cdba', 'dabc', 'dacb', 'dbac', 'dbca', 'dcab', 'dcba']`

Comment: I think that for this particular question "effort" would be post to one of more CS-oriented sites first to find name of the problem. Or post on SO itself with emphasis on "how this thing is called, because it is not permutations".

Comment: Speaking of mods, [here is a response I got from a mod on a question that was closed as too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27149214/distribute-numbers-randomly-in-javascript#comment42793712_27149214).

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I really wish people would get off of this idea that "no documented attempts" means the question automatically **must** be closed.  If the question is reasonably scoped without absurd implementation limits, not a "write my app for me" question, written clearly with clear start and end points, and it is a problem someone else *might* have in the future, then by closing it simply because someone did not "show their work", then you deprive any future user from the answers to the same question.

Here's some related discussions on MSE:

- [To flag or not to flag question that don't show own effort?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223480/to-flag-or-not-to-flag-question-that-dont-show-own-effort/223482#223482)
- [reason for Close: lack of research?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149137/reason-for-close-lack-of-research) (this is an older question, so the close reasons listed are out-dated, but the discussion is still relevant)

I think this fallacy comes from much of the discussion surrounding the removal of the "demonstrate a minimal understanding” close reason.  The close reason was <s>abused</s> used to close question that were too simple or where the close voters thought there was not enough evidence that the OP would be able to understand the answers.

- [Recent changes to close reasons on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252585/recent-changes-to-close-reasons-on-stack-overflow)
- [Improving "demonstrate a minimal understanding" close reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211080/improving-demonstrate-a-minimal-understanding-close-reason)
- [Are code questions without an attempt now on topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215596/are-code-questions-without-an-attempt-now-on-topic)

But to tie everything together, I think the best answer is in the words of [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) in his response to [Add something about "minimal effort" questions to the "Too broad" close reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224098/add-something-about-minimal-effort-questions-to-the-too-broad-close-reason/224104#224104)

> > In particular, questions that do not include an attempted solution are usually too broad.
>
> This is entirely incorrect.
>
> It's true that questions on solving large problems where the asker hasn't tried anything yet are often too broad - there's simply too much ground to cover for a single question.
>
> But many specific, answerable questions don't include attempted solutions because... There's nothing to attempt: either you know the answer or you don't. Indeed, this can be a *hallmark* of a properly-scoped question: have you managed to narrow it down to *the one piece you don't know* before asking?
>
> [If the asker identifies where they want to start, and where they want to end, but there are way too many pieces to fill in, then it is **Too Broad**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211080/improving-demonstrate-a-minimal-understanding-close-reason/215220#215220).

So for this specific question, I see everything needed to provide a response.  The problem has a limited scope (or looks to be a limited scope for someone without knowledge of python).  The start point and end point are clear.  It looks to be a problem someone else *might* have in the future (i.e. not too localized to a specific moment in time or place, or limited by absurdly specific implementation details).

The question certainly does appear to suffer from a lack of research so it probably is downvote worthy, but i don't see where any of the current close reasons fit.

Comment: So, you mean that *"here is my homework, give me any suggestions"* (in the meaning of, *"I'm expecting the whole code written for me"*), we should keep opened? I know that some of them may receive a well written answer, but won't then people use SO more as a homework writing service when they see that?

Comment: @TLama: when I come from google; I don't care whether the question I happen to land is a homework or not. If I have the same question; all I interested in is whether there is a solution (that is why I've used the search in the first place). Also, do you consider `"too broad"` and `"homework"` to be synonyms?

Comment: @TLama more often than not questions of that form are too broad because they are not reasonably scoped or they have intentionally absurd  limits.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Maybe not the popular answer, but the correct one.

Comment: If the question is reasonably scoped: 'my homework says to iterate over a list and return the largest element. Here's the list. How do I do this in language X?" It doesn't matter if it's homework or not. Downvote, sure -- but don't vote to close questions that are within our guidelines just because you don't like the fact the author is trying to 'get over'.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Code from homework questions are almost never usable in practice. You're raising a non-issue.

Comment: @simonzack: your statement is baseless. Your "almost never" happens more often than you think based on my personal experience. Widen your horizons (outside your comfort zone) to find cases where simple "homework" questions are useful.

Comment: Why did you put homework in quotation marks? Are your "horizons" so wide, that you are referring to homework-like questions as well?

Comment: @simonzack while I can't say why *homework* was in quotes, my opinion on the matter is the source of the question should not matter at all.  If the question otherwise fits the scope of the site, then it is a good question.  In general most bad homework questions are too broad or unclear simply because the author provides zero context to an absurd problem with odd limitations.

Comment: FWIW there is a very specific statement regarding "homework" or _homework_ in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) : _"Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."_ Unfortunately, it is somehow buried in the "off-topic" list -- so that leads to confusion to say the least.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I agree that it is confusing as I know others who use that phrase as a sledgehammer to close such questions, but I believe the intention of that statement is to provide guidance for the asker and provide a point of emphasis for commenters when trying to help users asking for help on homework.  I do not believe it was ever intended on being a site-wide policy.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Is there any mechanism in place that should dissuade me from VTCing questions just because I don't like them?

Comment: @tmyklebu No; although if you're doing something especially egregious, you may get a warning from a diamond moderator.  I don't know that that's ever happened, but it's not outside the realm of possibility. It depends on the circumstances.

Comment: When I first started I would see questions closed with no code (or some other reason) that would get the question closed. Some had easy answers and I always thought that it would be pandering to answer those types of questions. After reading this I'm going to reevaluate my voting/closing strategy. In my defense that is the perceived culture here

Comment: @Matt definitely appears to be part of the culture of a subset of the community.  I was actually not anticipating a positive response to this but it has annoyed me for a while.  1 person asks a valid question and we close it because we think it is lazy.  Now when someone else tries to do their own research to the same problem.  They will find the close question (assuming it wasn't deleted) and now have to go somewhere else.  Why does 1 person being lazy have to prevent dozens of others who aren't lazy from getting an answer?

Comment: The only problem I see with this is making answerers to do research (like find duplicates) on behalf of OP. I.e. how one should deal with nicely (or just ok) written questions about "How to split sting on 'x' character" where 'x' is varied through half of Unicode table - all will be ok, no need to show effort, can't be downvoted...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov why can't they be downvoted?  If the question shows no research, then that is a downvote reason.  But I agree in part on the duplicate issue.  It is easier to close for another reason rather than as a duplicate.  So if someone is doing just that, I'd rather they leave the question open than close it as "Too Broad".  There just needs to be more incentive to find and close as a duplicate to prevent people from answering easy dups.

Answer (score 27):

Let me start off by saying [@psubsee2003's answer is correct](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283185/16587). My answer isn't meant to compete with his (please upvote his answer), but it is meant to give a little bit of extra context as well as to state for the record that [I've undeleted and re-opened the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27885020/revisions) because it fits our criteria.

The question you're asking about is not too broad.

- It does not ask for multiple implementations
- It has a reasonably scoped problem set (get largest subsequence from a list in python)
- It shows us the inputs, and the expected outputs.

[Laziness (no attempt to solve the problem) has never been a reason to close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216491/what-happened-to-the-youre-just-lazy-close-vote-reason).

One of the commenters left a comment suggesting a diamond mod told them this was the right thing to do:

> because op failed to show the attempts and the answerer need to write all the code for him. A mod told me like that. –  Avinash Raj 5 hours ago

The funny thing is, [Robert Harvey never said that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270903/how-to-reduce-and-quickly-close-questions-that-are-merely-requirements).

> Don't confuse work orders with **"how do I do this specific thing"
>   questions**.
>
> "How to" questions are the most valuable of all questions, if the
>   answer is general enough to help other programmers. We want those
>   questions. We want the answers to those questions. Long live code
>   samples.
>
> Work orders are another story. We already have a close reason for
>   those: Too Broad. Use this close reason freely, **on those questions
>   where people just want you to complete their project for them**.

I can see the confusion.  Robert was talking about a specific problem, those people that post an entire homework assignment and say "Do this homework assignment for me."

That's different than a reasonably scoped question that happens to be a homework assignment.  Think the difference between solving one problem and implementing an entire project.

For our discussion, the 'one problem' is "How do I find the largest subsequence in a list in Python", and the project would be "Write a program that takes in a list and returns the largest subsequence."

It all comes down to scope and whether or not we have the necessary information to solve the problem. In this case, the problem is reasonably scoped and we have everything we need to solve it.

In general, feel free to downvote questions that you think don't show enough research effort. That's what the downvote button explicitly says.  Don't vote to close just because you don't like a question -- if it meets our criteria for being open, closing it simply sends the wrong message to the user and the rest of the community.

Comment: As a footnote to my answer (because I don't want to run into the five minute edit window edit),  when I say "Write a program that takes in a list..." I mean that that's the entirety of the question text. We see those a lot, a whole homework assignment just copy and pasted -- due to the nature of how they're written and what they're asking, they're generally too broad.  That isn't the case here.

Comment: unrelated:  [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27885020/4279) is about finding *all possible subsets* in a given character sequence (a power set), not *largest subsequence*.

Comment: Laziness used to be a reason to close crap questions indeed. We had "the poster must demonstrate a a minimum of knowledge of the topic being discussed". It was back in the ways when SO wasn't one big flood of crap...

Comment: Also there is absolutely no reason why we need to undelete and reopen this question. If it was closed for the wrong reason, close it for the right one. If there is no right option, then the SO moderation rules are severely broken and needs to be fixed. This is just a complete crap question that adds nothing to the site, there is no reason what-so-ever to preserve it.

Comment: Could this question not have been re-openened through the usual re-opening process? It's nice to have a mod doing the work but also the usual re-opening process should take place. Maybe it needs to be improved.

Comment: Re: "*Laziness (no attempt to solve the problem) ...*"  I would like to provide yet another link: [What happened to the “You're Just Lazy” close vote reason?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216491/what-happened-to-the-youre-just-lazy-close-vote-reason)

Answer (score 14):

Maybe my feeling on this one is based on the fact that I don't know Python, but I think it is *certainly* too broad. Is there one one answer, or only one canonical answer?

How many decent answers *are* there for this question?

Also, I strongly disagree with "giving a man a fish". The fact that no effort was documented means that we don't know what problem the OP had in solving the problem on his own. That means we're not helping the OP (or future readers) overcome that problem - we're just giving them a final answer.

Providing pieces of code that can be cut and pasted without understanding does not make the Internet a better place, in my opinion. It certainly doesn't improve the quality of the young co-workers I have to work with, as it encourages them to do nothing more than learn how to ask questions on [so] which are good enough to get an answer that seems to work for them.

Instead, we should encourage them to tell us what got in the way of them solving the problem for themselves. We should then teach them how to get over whatever speed bump (or brick wall) they have encountered. That will help those in the future who hit the same problem.

Comment: I absolutely understand this but it seems the "lacks minimal understanding" reason was rejected as close reason. What kind of search/research can you expect from someone with only minimal understanding? Also maybe you don't want to give the answer in order to not "give the man a fish" but maybe others just do. Should we punish them for giving an answer? I hope not. So all that remains is downvoting for lack of research and going on.

Comment: Sorry, I hope "yes". Otherwise we wind up with a lot of trivial questions and a lot of trivial answers, none of which are helpful over time. We do not want to degenerate into a "forum".

Comment: There won't be a lot of trivial questions if you downvote them (doesn't this already lead to a question ban?). And anyway all the trivial question will have low number of votes. If you would/could filter out all with negative votes you would never see them.

Comment: IMO, trivial questions are usually duplicates.  The issue is just finding the right duplicate and getting the question closed before people start providing answers.  Improvements to duplicate identification or incentives to close as a duplicate could certainly help.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just downvote if they lack research effort? The downvoting is fully justified. The tooltip of the downvote button says, a lack of (re)search is clearly a downvote reason.

I find it neither too broad nor unclear. It's quite specific and quite clear. It's understandable and a fitting answer can be easily conceived.

It's also roughly to do with programming. I can not exclude someone would learn something from it (from the answer in any case).

So don't close (unless some other close reason applies like duplicate for example) and just downvote. That will already have a quite negative impact on the privileges of the asker.

Answer (score 3):

Let me tell you what I believe is the real reason why it got closed:

## It's boring!

The question probably is too easy to figure out, or utterly uninteresting that people don't want to see them, and the *most effective way* to keep them out of the system is close them and fast. If you don't want a certain kind of questions being asked, you just simply prevent them from being answered, and that's what, in my opinion, happened here. They just picked a reason, any reason, to get rid of the boring question.

I will leave you https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/ to read. It's eye opening. There's another reference [in Unix.SE](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/595/41104):

> I certainly defer to the others here who are active participants -- but our general philosophy is to *heavily favor answerers*.
>
> We feel that the world is awash in questions, but not answers. Answers are the real unit of work in any Q&A system. Therefore, the only logical thing to do is to **maximize the happiness and enjoyment of answerers.**
>
> **If this means aggressively closing unworthy or uninteresting questions, so be it.** Without a community of people willing to answer questions, it really doesn't matter if there are questions at all, does it?

Comment: The only problem with this is their is no "General Reference" close reason anymore.  Presumably this means that being "General Reference" does not mean a question should be closed.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I don't see a problem with that. Almost any question that fits the "it's boring" would one or another way fit a close reason.

Comment: General reference absolutely should *not* mean that a question should be closed. Neither should questions be closed for being "too easy" (though questions that are "too easy" are almost always closable as *duplicates*). The issue isn't whether such questions are "too easy", or "boring" (also not a good reason to close), but whether they have shown enough lack of effort to the point that we really don't want to encourage more crap like that. I personally still feel we need a "this is blatantly a dump of a request somebody else gave you" close reason, but I'm in the minority on that one. :p

Comment: @neminem there are many crap questions, way too many. If no one is going to answer them, because they are crappy (in the wide sense), what should we do then?

Comment: Those bold quotes are so true.

Answer (score 1):

I think "Too broad" is not the right closing reason, but I think it is a pity that there is no good alternative for closing such questions. People who dump their homework like that don't care about downvotes, they just want a quick answer. If such a question is not closed it will be answered quickly as well.

To a certain point it's not bad to have a question and its answer on a Q&A site, but on the other hand, those questions have no value at all. People who would do a little research wouldn't need these questions, and people who don't obviously won't find it. So in the end it has no value at all for the historical archive of StackOverflow.

Apart from that, I think when such questions get answered, they will attract other poor questions. Eventually, this will create a lot of noise on StackOverflow and will become a demotivator for people who like to seriously help serious developers (no matter whether they are hobbyists, scholars or professionals). In short, I think those questions are the poison that will be the end of StackOverflow, and therefor it is important to have the means to close them quickly. By lack of a better option, closing as 'Too broad' would be the 'best' pick.

However, it doesn't fit. This question isn't too broad in that sense. The people who chose to have no 'lack of research' close vote reason apparently don't see it that way, so I guess the right thing to do would be to downvote it but not close it. But every time I see such question, I click *Close* in a vain hope that a proper close reason popped into life. But it never does. Sadly.

Answer (score -12):

The correct answer is "Off-topic - Why is this code not working?". There is no code and no error messages. The only criteria they seem to meet is the *desired output* one.

Comment: The question is not about code that is not working. They didn't forget to post the code, because there is no code yet. This closing reason is therefore -unfortunately- incorrect as well.