# Disagree with Review Audit for New Posts

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

In the case of the question "[Complex Bow and Arrow Design with a Dart Board and Quiver - CSS only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27587378/complex-bow-and-arrow-design-with-a-dart-board-and-quiver-css-only)", I felt it should be closed. The review queue, and apparently the readers disagree.

There is no attempt to solve the problem. It's just a request for a solution. I'm not impressed with the fact that an image was included in the question.

I'd love to know what was so great about this question as to make me fail a review audit.

Comment: Best thing you can do is to downvote the question/close it by hand. That may prevent it from coming up as an audit for somebody else.

Comment: "There is no attempt to solve the problem. It's just a request for a solution." Irrelevant. Lack of an attempt is not by itself a disqualification - this was [discussed previously today](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283185). Not that the question doesn't deserve to be closed on other grounds, of course.

Comment: People tend to get annoyed when they ask a question and someone who does NOTHING but lurk on this site closes it BECAUSE THEY DON'T HAVE AN ANSWER. Go figure...

Comment: If you're referring to me "only lurks", then please don't be shy.

Comment: @JohnSaunders your 5K+ answers and 40+ questions at SO make one wonder if you followed an advice given in [How does a lurker gain reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164035/165773) :)

Comment: The question has been deleted now, but I quite liked my animated bow and arrow answer :-(

Comment: Please DO NOT reopen or undelete the post. I do not want more downvotes!!!

Comment: @chipChocolate.py: Given that there is another upvoted answer, I guess the question sort of becomes the community's property. Even if it is re-opened, I guess you can still delete it (provided misterManSam takes his answer back because you cant delete a question which has an upvoted answer).

Comment: @Harry - Eventhough his answer derived from my own effort he is not the one getting downvotes. My answer and question both were downvoted not his. If that post is reopened, there are more chances that I will have 100 more downvotes. I don't think anyone would want that.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py It was getting downvoted because this question kept popping into the Hot Meta Posts box at the side which was drawing a lot of traffic to it. The [meta-tag:status-completed] tag on this question will actually prevent that from happening now. Only traffic that naturally came across this question would ever find its way to yours. If you could improve it into an actual question, I'm sure it wouldn't get downvoted any more.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py  You got far more reputation from the upvotes on the answer than you lost from the downvotes on the question. Even from the question alone, you've made +9 rep net.

Comment: Whoaa! What's happening? That post has been deleted and then undeleted twice. It is now again on the verge of being deleted for the third time! Are there any limits on the number of times a post could be deleted-undeleted, or can this (theoretically) go on for ever?

Comment: @abhitalks Theoretically, it could go on forever. But at some point (a short while ago), moderators/community managers step in and lock the post, temporarily or permanently, to end the cycle.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You're right, that question sucks. They clearly put no effort whatsoever into making an actual question, and were more focused on posting a blog to show off "hey, look at this cool thing I did!" It is pretty cool, and I imagine that's why it got so many upvotes in a month, but that's not what our site is for. It's been closed now and shouldn't bother other users as an audit any longer.

Comment: Even if the question sucked, the answers were actually pretty interesting and fun. It has now been deleted and I think it should not have been...

Comment: I thought this community are here to *help* others, not slag people off. I would refrain from calling the question to *'suck'*, and I feel this not the way of SO. The question itself was actually a TONNE better than 90% of questions posted daily, so i'm surprised (and annoyed) to hear that the OP felt that they needed to delete the question. Be as it may, obviously some users may have upvoted it because it was 'cool', how can you say that it was a 'blog' (which it wasn't), and then say '*that's why it got upvotes.'* Indeed, you are a moderator, but I feel this to be quite narrow minded IMHO.

Comment: @jbutler483 The question was not better than 90% of other questions. It's a terrible question. I think you may be confusing question quality with answer quality. The answers *were* amazing. The question was crap. And no, I don't have any problem saying a question is crap when it's crap.

Comment: @animuson: So hence if the 'answers were good', why would the OP/community feel the need to delete it? I'm sure you can't suggest somewhere along the line where you haven't seen a *good question receive bad answers*, nor *a bad question receiving good answers*. They are mutually exclusive. Why should future readers not 'see' what was implemented when they come across a similar scenario? And No, I'm not *confusing* anything. Because of this, you've de-voided future readers from seeing those 'amazing' answers.

Comment: @jbutler483 I've said it many times before: good answers don't save bad questions. If he wants future readers to see it, he can very easily go post it in a blog somewhere, or he can shape the question up into an actual question, rather than a rephrasing of "This is what I'll be showing you how to do today."

Comment: No, but if the *question could be edited into a better one* then go ahead. Oh wait, hang on, IT WAS FORCE-DELETED. Doesn't that suggest to you something? (Oh, and BTW, as mentioned many times before, not every question **can** have attempts). Furthermore, a **good answer** obviously **answered the question**. So obviously, there was a question ***somewhere** that was answered.

Comment: @jbutler483 Just FYI, the question was deleted by ordinary 20k users, no moderator involved in the deletion.

Comment: @jbutler483 You do realize that the person who asked the question is the one that posted the answer? Hence its "blog-like" nature. It was clearly an attempt to just post something cool they did, with no real effort into making it an actual question. The other answer was just a reply to that on how to do something even cooler (make the bow shoot the arrow), which doesn't technically even answer the question. Unless you count that "suggestions for improvement are welcome" bit as a legitimate part of the question, in which case, the question is even worse.

Comment: There was a question. there was an answer. Isn't that was SO if for? As far as i'm aware, OP had a question, and eventually solved he answer (jsyk, loads of questions here go unanswered because they were asked badly). So at least this one had the ability to be 'answered'. As for the 'other answer', improvements/alternatives can also be very much valid answers. But you seem to be of the opinion that 'self answered' questions are bad (IMO, they're better than unanswered ones). But obviously you'll argue till kingdom come, and quite frankly, I have other things to be at.

Comment: Kindly note that being a moderator does not make you 'always' right. you can be wrong, and IMHO, I think you are in this case.

Comment: @jbutler483 Self-answered questions aren't bad. They're very good, but only if done correctly, which this one was not. You don't seem to be grasping that the question here is not acceptable by any standards on Stack Overflow. To evaluate a question, you have to pretend there are no answers. The answers are not at all relevant to the question's quality. If you looked at the question, on its own, without any answers to it at all, could you honestly say that it was a good question that should be reopened? If so, I'm afraid that you don't have a very firm grasp on the topicality of our site.

Comment: That question sucks and deserves downvotes for lack of effort when viewed in isolation, but that is no reason to close it. The only potentially applicable reason for closing is that answering it properly would be too much work (→ too broad), but an adequate self-answer demonstrates that the question is answerable.

Comment: @Gilles: I am still 50-50 on whether to close the question or not. But now that I see that quite a lot of users think of it to be broad (judging by the upvotes on meta), I wonder if leaving it open because of a self answer sets a good precedent. After all, all users with broad questions can claim that eventually they will themselves add an answer once they have it and want their question to remain open which I don't think is correct.

Comment: @Harry If they haven't posted a self-answer that actually does answer the question, then there is no proof that the question isn't too broad. So if the question looks too broad, lacking a proof of the contrary, it should be closed as such. If we applied your reasoning, we'd close all the canonical questions too (and yes, I know some people do that, and it's bad, so stoppit, willya?).

Comment: @Gilles: What I meant to say is something very similar to what animuson already had said. We should look at the question in isolation and decide whether it is broad or not. Every question can be answered given time and effort. For self answered question, the OP already has the answer and so posts it immediately but for a non self answered one,  others have to be given time to find it. But in most cases the question gets closed as broad even before somebody can attempt. A question that looks broad for 1 person need not be broad for another. But then, lets just say we agree to disagree :)

Answer (score 6):

Finding yourself at odds with a decision that the community made *is not failing*, it's community moderation working as it was intended to work. The audits are stupid, and I'm strictly referring to intelligence - they expect (A) and scream if they get (! A). That's all they do, and if you were actually paying attention and simply had a dissenting opinion, *then ignore them squawking at you entirely*.

That said, there *appears* to be a sufficient amount of entropy that manifested *prior* to this being presented to you which would strongly indicate controversy (and that it probably should not be presented). I'm going to look at this as a possible bug, because (if I recall correctly), tweaks were made so that this type of thing rarely (if ever) showed up.

tl;dr; - If you do honest work in the queues, feel free to tell the audit nanny to go to hell and that you're entitled to your own opinion. Scream it, if you want, right at your monitor (results vary according to where you work).

As to the matter of the question itself, [that's being talked about over here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283548/the-css-bow-and-arrow-question-is-now-on-the-verge-of-being-reopened-after-havin).