# Why are we able to vote to delete or undelete over and over again?

Tags: support, feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-delete, vote-to-undelete

Currently a delete/undelete *war* is going on on on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27587378/complex-bow-and-arrow-design-with-a-dart-board-and-quiver-css-only, which I've posted about here today: [The CSS Bow and Arrow question is now on the verge of being reopened after having previously been deleted. Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283548/the-css-bow-and-arrow-question-is-now-on-the-verge-of-being-reopened-after-havin).

**Update**: The linked question has now been locked as deleted (following 3 more delete votes from 3 new people who hadn't voted before). But this post still stands as similar situations will no doubt happen in future.

The problem is that the same users are voting to undelete the question after it's been deleted, as can be seen in the question's [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27587378/revisions):

[image: Example]

In this particular case, 6 of us have voted to delete the question, but only 4 different people have voted to undelete it - one of the undelete voters being the user who asked the question in the first place. More people believe that it should be deleted than undeleted, but because we're allowed to vote to delete or undelete as many times as we like, the question is currently open again.

```
Let o = unique voters and - be the user who asked the question:

Votes to delete:      oooooo
Votes to undelete:    ooo-
```

Should delete/undelete votes be limited to only allow one vote per question per user?

Comment: Related from Uber-Meta: [Why is it possible to vote for deletion/undeletion more than once?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9431/why-is-it-possible-to-vote-for-deletion-undeletion-more-than-once).  Jarrod's answer suggests that they were waiting to for signs of abuse to decide to implement.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm the good guy or the bad guy in this case...

Comment: @psubsee2003 _waiting for signs of abuse_ might take quite a while, given that moderators have means to tame it on case-by-case basis, using [content dispute lock](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237263/165773). Un/delete disputes involving 10Kers seem to happen much less frequently compared eg to close/reopen ones involving 3K users

Comment: @gnat don't disagree - just paraphrasing what Jarrod and Shog said in the linked post.

Comment: @psubsee2003 neither do I, only commented to complement reasoning about that "waiting..." to point out related feature (content dispute locks) that wasn't mentioned in discussion there

Comment: @rene Probably the good guy since the OP of this topic also voted to delete the question...

Comment: Can't address the technical issues of "Why it is possible". Howeever, this is clearly a case of SO being used instead of a personal blog. While it's not a platonic ideal of a question, it has its redeeming qualities. The answer is so very instructive - I fail to see how deleting the question improves the quality of contents on SO.

Comment: The answer is of such good quality that it should remain for historical significance. There are much worse POS questions that are not deleted from the past that have much less interest in them, after all.

Comment: @TylerH a great answer can be published to the web anywhere. I do not think anyone will be coming to Stack Overflow to ask how to draw a bow and arrow and dart board with CSS only.

Comment: @Compass You're already wrong, because someone already did. Quirkier questions have also been asked and answered before. There are millions of users on Stack Overflow... you can't say any given question will never be asked.

Comment: @TylerH Someone did it, because the person who posted it *answered his own question with the solution afterwards*. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283558/2958086

Comment: @Compass It's unclear if your concerns match up with the concerns of Tim Post (in which case an argument in the defense of the subject Q&A can easily be made) or if your concern is that it was simply a self-answered question, in which case those are allowed and you have no ground upon which to stand.

Comment: @TylerH Subject Q&A is fine. But the premise should be that the question is something that is, as mentioned by Tim, practical, and not showboating. The question here would have been far better suited for PPCG than SO.

Comment: @Compass I don't know what PPCG stands for, but I think the term "showboating" is inaccurate. It is an unexpected Q&A post, and it was a pretty damn specific topic, but the problem I have with using that as a reason for disallowing it is that Tim Post says one of the criteria for Q&A posts is to *solve a very specific problem*. This speaks to a larger issue with Stack Overflow and it's overly-vague Close Vote reasons due to not wanting to step on peoples' toes a la Summer of Love.

Comment: @TylerH [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/39915/pixel-art-episode-1-display-super-mario/) If this person asked the question there, it would be on-topic, even as a self-answer.