# Question about entire library's compatibility not "too broad"?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I reviewed this question as "too broad" because it's asking about an entire library:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/15004952

If you look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41633278/can-we-use-all-features-of-log4j2-if-we-use-it-along-with-slf4j-api) it lists 10 places where the library will not work with the other library, but maybe there are more?

How is this question not "too broad"?

Comment: "If you look at the answer it lists 10 places where the library will not work with the other library, but maybe there are more?" -- So if there were, say, only three unavailable features the question wouldn't be to broad? That would be a rather arbitrary criterion.

Comment: The fact that someone chose to give a long, comprehensive answer doesn't affect whether or not the question itself is too broad. The way the question is posed, it literally looks like a "yes"/"no" question to me—hardly too broad, although maybe problematic for another reason.

Comment: reminds me of [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326951/are-questions-asking-for-feature-sets-of-specific-software-versions-on-topic) and both of those "list" questions are currently open.

Comment: @NathanOliver I grieve each time I remember them...

Answer (score 16):

The question itself is reasonably scoped. Taking out the specific libraries in question, it can be rephrased as:

> I have code written against interface `X`, the concrete implementation of which will be `Y`. Does interface `X` express all the features available in `Y`?

Which is an entirely reasonable question which can in fact be answered with a single *yes* or *no*.

> If you look at the answer it lists 10 places …

That was not what was being asked though. [Remko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41635246/476) goes above and beyond the call of duty here to voluntarily provide a list of examples where `X` fails to expose features in `Y`. The OP didn't ask for that and this is a *great, helpful bonus* to an already helpful answer.

Comment: That rephrasing would be a yes/no question, which we all agree aren't useful questions, either.

Comment: While it *can* be answered by a mere "yes" or "no", a *good* answer would certainly be *yes, because it's guaranteed by A* or *no, because [one good counter example]/[one solid reason why it's impossible]*. I think the existing answer demonstrates that well too. The question as such ticks all the right boxes for me: 1. clear problem statement, 2. just enough context to flesh it out, 3. clear expected answer which *can* be very short if necessary, 4. not necessarily obvious solution.

Comment: We care more about what the question ask for (or could be interpreted as asking for), and do not trust that the answerers will go above and beyond. If you are going to craft a question, you should make sure that you will not leave room for yes/no answers. That was the [whole point of this initiative](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341987/792066), make sure that no way can answerers interpret that a subpar answer will be allowed. BTW, you haven't fixed the problem with this question, and I would guess that unless someone ask what features the OP needs, it will then be degraded to unclear.

Comment: Dragging the resource request initiative into this seems a bit strawmanny. Again: the question can be answered in a perfectly concise manner as is. "Yes/no" would be a technically acceptable answer, but without further explanation it would be a *poor* answer (because it leaves open a *"why?"*). "Yes/no, because X" would be a *good* answer. What really happened is "No, because X, Y, Z, the kitchen sink and BTW this is how a kitchen sink works". *That* is "above and beyond"; but that's nowhere near required. The first two or three paragraphs would have been great already.

Comment: Wait. You know that the wording of the question accepts bad answers as valid and you say ["this is fine"](https://i.imgur.com/c4jt321.png)? And how is that link not relevant, since I'm objecting the wording of your "would be" question?

Comment: You're mincing my words too finely. Just "yes/no" would *not be a good answer*. I may also say it would be an *insufficient* answer to the question. An *appropriate* or *good answer* would be *yes, because X*. Which ["is fine"](https://i.imgur.com/c4jt321.png) with me indeed.

Comment: Yet you word the question in a way that it would be a valid answer, which was why I linked that post by Shog: *FLASH NEWS! Wording a question the right way **is important**!* (hint: point 4). The alternative question proposed isn't a good question because it explicitly ask for a yes/no answer. So, unless that problem is fixed, this question remains too broad.

Comment: I personally cannot make heads or tails of what is being asked in the question. The rephrasing in this answer is technically wrong, which is the most important aspect to consider here. slf4j-api is an interface, that abstracts other logging frameworks. Question is asking whether using the official Slf4j-Log4j2 binding supports Log4j2, which is a _very_ weird thing to ask...... There are 3 players here: the facade which is Slf4j-api, the binding which is Slf4j-Log4j2 and the implementation which is Log4j2. The question does not relate at all to Log4j. But I wonder which player it relates to.

Comment: Question should be closed as unclear, until OP can explain what it is they are actually looking for. Is it that they want to use Log4j2 specific feature and unaware that the binding supports it? Or the other way around? Or they're wondering if a Slf4j feature has an equivalent with the Log4j2 binding? Each player has their sets of specific features.... Of course, if you go with the "They're asking for _all of it_ and have no idea what they're actually looking for, then it definitely is too broad.

Comment: @Tunaki I don't know, question seems pretty clear to me: we've got code written against Slf4 APIs, now wondering whether we can use all Log4j (2.x) features with that. I can see where the phrasing might be slight awkward, but not completely so.

Comment: Note that if you want to go completely reductio ad absurdum, the answer should be pretty obvious: no, a generic interface probably does *not* expose everything in a library. But that's a different topic.

Comment: This is actually very close to [this Meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340229/1743880). There is a seemingly simple question that actually open a gigantic can of worms. 1st camp knows about the worms, knows OP doesn't and desperatly want to focus the question on the ones OP cares about, thus judging the question unclear. 2nd camp knows about the worms and assumes OP wants all of them, thus judging the question too broad (or doesn't know but assumes there are lots of worms from experience with other technologies). 3rd camp says "What's wrong with you? I like worms".

Comment: Eventually, someone will edit it into something like what is proposed here, radically changing the thing, turning it into a yes/no question, but that will mostly satisfy all parties involved. Personally, I still disagree with that conclusion as I consider it completely useless...

Comment: @Tunaki The discussion about clarity is a red herring. The natural interpretation of the question is the one offered by deceze a few comments above ("I don't know, question seems pretty clear to me: [...]"). It only begins to seem unclear once one starts (borrowing deceze's turn of phrase) mincing its words too finely in search of alternative interpretations, which is only necessary if one disregards the natural interpretation (e.g. because it is considered too broad -- "too broad", however, is not the same as "meaningless").

Comment: @duplode So you're part of camp 3, nothing wrong with that... It starts being unclear when one, like myself, wants to turn it into a question trying to answer the specific issue OP has...

Comment: @Tunaki My point is that the discussion about whether the question should be closed (as well as the close votes) should be primarily based on what the question currently is, and not on some hypothetical reformulation. (Though of course, as you say, considering such hypotheticals is useful when trying to salvage a question -- but that comes *after* the decision about whether the question, in its current form, should be closed.)

Comment: @duplode Ah, but the entire argument is this answer relies on a hypothetical reformulation...

Comment: @Tunaki You may rightly be concerned that *the answer* turns out to be too broad ("can of worms"), something the OP may appear to be unaware of. That does not automatically make the *question* too broad though! Perhaps the correct answer is *"No, but [can of worms], so really, rethink what you really want."*

Comment: And personally, I admit not seeing the value in such an answer @deceze. It would be the correct answer to the edit proposed here. Then the good answer would have to list the worms, and we're back at square one. And the "correct" answer "yes/no" is not that useful to me, simply because it begs the question "but why?"

Comment: @Tunaki This answer implicitly claims that the reformulation it proposes does not change the meaning of the question. ("Reformulation" is perhaps a slightly weak word for what I meant -- for instance, trivial rephrasings that preserve the meaning of the question aren't supposed to be covered.)

Answer (score -5):

The question is not too broad, and the fact that "it's asking about an entire library" does not make it too broad. The fact that one of the libraries is a wrapper for the other is entirely sufficient to satisfctorily limit the scope of a question about their compatibility. Furthermore, a list of ten short bullet points definitely doesn't make the answer too long. Even if there were enough incompatibilities (e.g. several dozens) to make this answer format unwieldy, the answerer would have reasonable alternatives, such as:

> There are several incompatibilities between Bar and Foo. The main ones are:
>
> *[A list summarising the key incompatibilities.]*
>
> A full list of Foo features unsupported by Bar is provided by [the Foo compatibility page](http://example.com/) at Bar's documentation.

Or even:

> Bar only supports a small fraction of Foo's full API. Here are the available features:
>
> *[A list of the few things Bar actually makes possible.]*
>
> Further details are available from [the Foo compatibility page](http://example.com/) at Bar's documentation.

Comment: The fact that your proposal is to provide an *incomplete* answer to the question is precisely how you know that the question *is* Too Broad.  When all you can do is provide an incomplete answer and link to an *actual* answer elsewhere then that pretty conclusively tells you that the question is too broad.

Comment: @Servy In this case, I disagree that an answer must be exhaustive to be acceptable. An answer which points out that several key parts of the target API are unavailable through the wrapper while suggesting relevant documentation as further reading is perfectly useful in this context, and doesn't invalidate the question.

Answer (score -9):

> Question about entire library's compatibility not “too broad”?

That's not even a question. Oh, yes, you can put an interrogation mark at the end, but that's not a question in the way SO wants, because the would be "answer" to that "question" is a compatibility matrix. That post is asking for a compatibility matrix, and such thing aren't Q&A's.

How then, would it be a Q&A? Something like this:

> ## What changes I have to do to my code to continue using x featute from x-1.0 in 2.0?
>
> I use this feature in this manner `enter code here`, I see changes a,
>   b and c on the new version, how can I adapt my code since the new
>   version isn't backwards compatible?