# Why is this a failed first-post audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, needs-more-focus, first-post-review

I believe I've found a question that does not fit the standards of an audit.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/11203084

[image]

This question is clearly too broad about getting started with a library.

I WANT MY FAIL BACK D:

No but seriously, might want to remove this one from the audit list (if that's how that works).

Comment: You failed it because the automatic process that selects audit questions mistook it for a good question because of the sheer volume of upvotes.  But the question does seem too broad, and the length of the answer pretty much confirms it.

Comment: so, I may very well be wrong, but I remember reading in comments somewhere on meta that audits are not in a list but auto-selected from posts with little controversy (only one downvote here. Probably never got a close-vote either). Go on the original post and downvote/CTV as too broad.

Comment: I get the feeling this is a lot similar to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283548/the-css-bow-and-arrow-question-is-now-on-the-verge-of-being-reopened-after-havin/. It's a self-answered question with a very long, explanatory answer, but in reality it's nothing more than a blog post that doesn't belong here. I've voted to close it as *Too Broad*.

Comment: That question is atrocious and needs to be deleted.

Comment: @Magisch Yet the answer is incredibly valuable... As you can see by the people panicking in the comments about archiving it so it isn't lost forever. Isn't this what Community Wiki is for?

Comment: @ThomasBoby As it stands, the answer is still off topic for stack overflow, so it should be deleted off here (Maybe they can put it elsewhere if they cherish it so much, its not for here) too. I can't vote to delete so my opinion doesn't matter much here anyways.

Comment: Why delete when you can close it and still preserve the data? Off topic doesn't warrant a delete, spam and rude stuff do. I've been helped many times by off topic questions

Comment: @ThomasBoby No, that's not what CW is for.  CW is there to indicate that a post is not authored by any one person, and that it's creation is a collaboration of any number of people, and that others are encouraged to make meaningful edits to the *content* of the post in their own edits, if they feel it would improve the answer.  None of that applies to this post.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Off-topic doesn't neccessarily warrant deletion if it's only a bit off-topic, and otherwise good content. This one might thus qualify for keeping... Anyway, while spam and offensive certainly and quite unambiguously need to be pruned (if it cannot be or is not worth salvaging by editing), it need be neither to deserve being cleaned away.

Comment: This is *definitely* worth keeping and should not be deleted. I agree it's a bad audit, but I'm even on the fence about whether or not it should be closed. We proactively close potentially problematic questions to keep down problems. In this case, the line is blurred because it was a self-answered question where the self answer was of *superb* quality. You couldn't ask for a much better contribution to the site. But the heuristics for what makes a good question aren't needed when you already have the answer(s) to judge it by.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> No but seriously, might want to remove this one from the audit list (if that's how that works).

Then vote to close the question.  You still haven't, despite being convinced that the question should be closed.  If you did vote to close it, the question would be ineligible as an audit from then on.

Comment: Good idea, forgot to do that