# Why was this VLQ flag declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, specific-question, declined-flags, low-quality-posts

I came upon a question that showed no effort to solve the problem. It would fit under the debated "Do my work" flag, but since there's not one I just flagged it as Very Low Quality.

A moderator reviewed it and declined the flag, although I'm not sure what about this question disqualifies it from the VLQ title.

The question has a pretty straightforward answer, so it's not too broad, it just doesn't warrant being answered because it's looking for free coding work to be done.

If this isn't a VLQ question, what is?

Question in question:
[How to style input type=radio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28456470/how-to-style-input-type-radio)

Comment: I absolutely agree we need a separate flag when people are asking us to do their work. It is so disrespectful that very low quality, off topic, unclear, etc. are not even close to the actual thing we want to sign with that flag. Since we are answering questions for free, we should have a means to show that someone was asking a disrespectful question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A few reasons:

Very Low Quality means: "This is garbage, and should be deleted by a moderator right now. There is no hope of salvation for this post."

Does this post fit that criteria?

Unequivocally no.

In fact, all the OP needs to do (or anyone else so inclined), is pose an actual question. Right now there isn't one.

The second reason is that it doesn't need a moderator's attention.

It could be closed by the community as "unclear what you're asking" (no actual question posed) or it could be closed as "problems must include a problem statement, code to reproduce it, etc.".

I also believe closing it through normal channels would let the OP know what's wrong with it, and specifically what needs to be improved before it's reopened. If they choose to do that, great! If not, it'll get deleted in time.

Why ask for a moderator to summarily delete the post if the community can handle it through normal closing procedures?

Your best bet here would be to cast a close vote if you could; flag for closure if you can't, and in all cases: use your downvotes. That's how these sorts of questions are blocked — when their posters are banned because they have lots of downvoted questions.

Contrary to popular opinion; [lack of research effort is not (and has never been) a reason to close a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283191/16587). It is definitely a reason to downvote a question, however.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll try to keep that in mind. Perhaps it would help to denote which of the flags actually bother moderators. I wasn't aware at the time that VLQ went straight to a moderator. I thought that was reserved for the "Flag for moderator" flag only.

Comment: @leigero They go to us after an hour if the community hasn't resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you read the description of the Very Low Quality Flag, it reads:

> This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

While that question appears to have problems, it certainly does not have **severe** content problems that can't be fixed with some editing.  The Very Low Quality flag should be used for posts that are just nonsense.

- Is it gibberish - *if so, flag it as VLQ*
- Is the post at least understandable that someone with the right knowledge can attempt to fix it - *if not, flag it as VLQ*
- If the post has code, is the code understandable (more on this below) - *if not, flag it as VLQ*

To expand on the 3rd bullet regarding code understandablity, you would use this very rarely.  I've only used this in cases where someone obviously copy and pasted code that is incomplete or is riddled with so many errors, typos and syntax errors that no one except the original author can fix it, and usually I would comment first to give them a chance to fix it before flagging it.