# Should I flag broad questions as "very low quality"?

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags

I flagged a question which was waaaaaay too broad, I flagged it as "low quality". The flag got declined by a mod but the question is now marked as "on hold" for being too broad,

Did I mis-flag the question?
Does this count as a black mark against me as a flagger?

I looked to [stackoverflow.com/help/flagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging) for help and found nothing relevant.

Comment: That was a quick downvote, did I use the wrong tag?

Comment: Low quality means that it needs to be deleted immediately. Being too broad doesn't necessarily qualify as low quality.

Comment: @bluefeet That's misleading because according to  Andy, I need to click on `should be closed...` which in my mind means `needs to be deleted immediately` whereas low quality suggests it needs intervention to recover it...

Comment: Closed != deleted

Comment: @SebastianTroy Closed/On-Hold doesn't mean deleted. It allows a user to edit the question with the possibility of being reopened.  Once it's deleted, it's gone and unlikely to be restored.

Comment: Check out [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285927/why-was-this-vlq-flag-declined) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265764/3093387) for some previous discussion of the difference between VLQ flagging and closing posts.

Comment: @josilber shame VLQ and low quality aren't matched when I search, though I admit I should have seen the `Am I misusing the “Very Low Quality” flag?` question!

Comment: I've tended to handle these based on the guidance received here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288440/under-the-new-triage-system-when-and-how-should-moderators-act-on-very-low-qua

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it's "too broad", flag it as "too broad", not low quality.

You can do this by selecting `Flag` -> `Should be closed...` -> `too broad`.

Comment: I'm never sure when selecting an option instantly submits the flag or gives me more options to choose from...

Comment: @SebastianTroy, if it has an ellipsis (`...`) you get more options when you click on the radio option. You don't have to click `flag` to get the next window.

Comment: Also nothing is submitted until you click the flag button on the bottom right hand corner.

Comment: Stop flagging things until you are sure...