# Does a priority exist in the close queue? (Close flags in pending status)

Tags: support, flags, vote-to-close

I'm trying to understand the mechanics behind the close votes.

I have a few triage reviews which I flagged to close because of "Needs details or clarity".

Take, as an example, two of them:

- An ["old" one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25087440) of seven days ago is still in pending status (Unsalvageable × 3, Requires Editing × 1)
- A [more recent one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25102148) that has already been closed despite I'm the only one who chose to close it

From ["Flag has been active for months"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266842/flag-has-been-active-for-months), I read that close votes could just send posts in the close queue (my vote is as a suggestion to close); but in this case why has a more recent post been closed **before** an older one (that IMO should be closed)?

Isn't there a "priority" in the queues? (Example: decide if to close or not depending on the arrival time in the queue.)

What is the workflow that brings to a post closure?

Comment: posts that got a recent vote do get a higher chance to be shown to a reviewer in the close vote queue. The exact sorting algorithm is burried in complex code.

Comment: You can check the post time line https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59757869/timeline. By clicking the almost invisible arrow just under the downvote button. And see the other close vote. So in fact you were the only one. It didn't get close and went to improvement queue. Where people re-review and closed it.

Comment: Here is a description of the process https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252048/question-flags-queues-edits-roomba-community-how-does-this-actually-work/300659#300659. Unsalvagable question from triage goes into the close review queue. Also I believe that Improvement queue does not have vote close. So a mod had to step in an close the second one.

Comment: with regards to questions triaged as unsalvageable, unfortunately its [first close review timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/25087979). There is a feature request to improve handling of these cases: [In close queue, prioritize questions triaged as unsalvageable to unconditionally stay on top](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370030/839601)

Comment: So, there is a mix between new tasks and old ones; this is why I have old reviews in pending status and new ones already "completed". Thanks a lot