# Is "How do I convert code from this language to this language" too broad?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, needs-more-focus

For context: [Post request with c# with TLSx1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30599389/2587435)

I see questions like this all the time. To me it reads as *"Rumor has it Stack Overflow is a coding service. Can you convert this code for me from language Y to language Z?"*.

For all we know the OP has no understanding of language Z. This is just laziness and I don't condone it in any way. In the past the close reason *"... must show a minimal understanding..."* would have sufficed as a reason to close, but that reason no longer exists.

When I see questions like this, I will automatically vote to close as too broad. Sometimes I will follow these questions, and see that there have been no additional close votes. So either other reviewers don't agree it is too broad, or they don't know the topic enough to agree. But one doesn't need to know the language to understand it's a *"gimme da codez"* question.

One discussion I found interesting is [Is “too broad” a valid reason to close a question that doesn't show any research effort?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283177/2587435). Quoting the [accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283185/2587435):

> I really wish people would get off of this idea that "no documented attempts" means the question automatically must be closed. If the question is reasonably scoped without absurd implementation limits, not a "write my app for me" question, written clearly with clear start and end points, and it a problem someone else might have in the future, then by closing it simply because someone did not "show their work", then you deprive any future user from the answers to the same question.

This is conflicting with my view of the question. It a clearly defined question (or at least problem statement), and yes maybe others may find it useful in the future, but *"no documented attempts"* does (IMO) mean the same as *"write my app for me"*.

So I'm just wondering whether or not, specifically, if *"How do I convert this code?"* (with the OP showing no understanding - could be interpreted as showing no attempt) is too broad (or should even be closed for a different reason). I just want to make sure I'm not voting to close questions, that should *not* be closed.

Comment: "How to convert this code" == "Write this app for me". It's a lazy OP anyway - a Google search for `C# curl` will give him everything he needs.

Comment: I would normally take the approach of explaining the given code in the ***context*** of the requested language

Comment: No documented attempts does not mean they have not made attempts. Sometimes it's difficult to tell the difference between a poorly written question (lacking code) from a newer SO user and a poorly written question from an incapable user who's unwilling to try on their own.

Comment: For all we know the OP has no understanding of language Y either.

Comment: I see LESS/Sass questions like this *all the time*.  In nearly every case, the asker has no clue what the code is doing in the original.  The question would *always* be better asked without even mentioning the other language (eg. "how do I write a loop" vs. "how do I translate this code I have no idea what it is even doing").

Answer (score 62, accepted):

## Yes.

Translating code between languages isn't something you can ask of volunteers.  My opinion is a bit more forceful in that their understanding of the languages is irrelevant; if they're asking blatantly that they want code in language A to be in language B, they're asking in the wrong place on the Internet.

However, **there is an exception.**

If the question is asking for help on an approach to translate a question from one language to another, then it may have a chance.  Some things to look for would be:

- Is it concise or otherwise reasonably scoped?
- Does the code present actually compile in one of the languages?
- Is there a clearly defined problem in their conversion efforts?  Do they highlight it?
- Do they provide any compilation messages or examples of aberrant behavior?

If a question has most of those points, I don't see a problem with it sticking around.

Answer (score 8):

In general, questions of such nature are too broad and the OP is looking for some free coding service. I see the following exceptions.

1. When a language does not support a feature. E.g. How do you translate an expression in C/C++ that uses the conditional operator to python (which does not have that operator)?
2. When a naive translation of a block of code results in performance penalties.
3. When a block of translated code can be expressed better in the new language. E.g using list comprehension in python might be better than using a simple for loop.

An example that I ran into today that looks like a good question to me: [Python-like C++ decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679445/python-like-c-decorators)

Comment: Since when does Python not have `a if c else b` as an equivalent to C++'s `c ? a : b`? Or are you thinking of a different "conditional operator"?

Comment: @tepples, it's the same thing I am thinking of. In the case of C/C++ that is a standard operator. In the case of Python, that's the equivalent code but Python does not support the operator as a native operator.