# Why I was blocked to ask questions?

Tags: support

I recently posted a question about getting help to conver a programming language onto another and was blocked to ask again. Why is that ?

Comment: [related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296126/839601)

Answer (score 2):

You were blocked for the reasons [laid out here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

A few notes:

- self deleted zero/negatively scored questions count towards the ban
- You can get out of the ban by improving your questions.

Here are the questions you can't see because they're too old:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532284/c-to-plain-c-error
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43404451/whatis-the-full-content-of-context-structure-extendedregisters

For your other negatively scored questions, a few tips:

- Ask about the specific issue you have. In your case [you had a question about equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57963078/how-can-i-convert-this-javascript-to-c) but your question was broader than that (though not 'too broad' in our textual definition). Consider editing the question down to the specific issue you have.
- If your question is programming related, make that abundantly clear. [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53459983/how-to-enable-disable-a-parent-keyframe-track-in-sony-vegas-15) does not look like it's related to programming (but I don't know enough to say that authoritatively).
- This question meets all of our requirements; looking at it I am unclear as to [why it was downvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35256413/rgbtoxyz-convertion-error?noredirect=1).
- Some [need to be targetted to a programming language to be on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338488/standard-deviation-addition-and-subtraction); in this case it isn't.
- This question has the same issue your first question above did; scope the question down [to the specific part you have an issue with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407811/converting-excel-formula-to-c).