# Exactly what does "document new learnings and solutions" mean in the description of the OverflowAI Visual Studio Code extension?

Tags: support, overflow-ai

The [initial description of the OverflowAI Visual Studio Code extension](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/07/27/announcing-overflowai) says:

> Meeting users in Slack is helpful, but we wanted to do more. Developers spend a lot of their time in an IDE and Stack Overflow wants to help coders find solutions without breaking their flow. To do that, we’re working on an IDE extension for Visual Studio Code powered by OverflowAI. This extension pulls in validated content from both the public platform and your private Stack Overflow for Teams instance to provide your developers with a personalized summary of how to solve their problems efficiently and effectively, allow them to dig deeper where needed, ***and then document new learnings and solutions.***

Exactly what does the last line mean? Is it just some sort of marketing empty buzzword or does it imply something else?
More specifically, does this betray the intention to train the model on the users code in some way? Or it is simply hinting at some way to post an answer directly from inside Visual Studio Code (again, using the user code as an input)?

---

Thanks to [Peter Mortensen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/63550/this-is-not-a-forum)’s comment, [another line caught my eye](https://stackoverflow.co/labs/code-editor/):

> Highlight code to explain the code.

In order to be able to explain the code, the client extension component has to send the code to some server, probably owned by Prosus.
I doubt any company would allow their developers to use an extension that has the ability to "upload" part of the company developed application code to some other company, regardless of the nature of said company.
This plug-in already looks like something that will be strictly forbidden in any workplace.

... There is a reason many company tell their employees to NOT use those "Power Point like" online tools to make presentations.

Comment: Related (blog post): *[Announcing OverflowAI](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/07/27/announcing-overflowai/?cb=1)*. And *[Stack Overflow for Visual Studio Code meets you where you work](https://stackoverflow.co/labs/code-editor/)* (Stack Overflow Labs) - *"The Stack Overflow for Visual Studio Code is a paired programmer that pulls in validated content from Public and Private Stack Overflow to provide developers with a personalized summary of how to efficiently solve problems as well as insights to expand their knowledge."*

Comment: I'm guessing they are using GPTs to summarize code, a common use case. Pass the code in with a prompt that says "summarize what this code does at a high level" or similar. It's sort of harmless-ish, but also fairly useless in my experience. Having worked on a large codebase that has been completely GPT summarized to create per-file docs, everything it's generated is obvious and non-insightful, so I basically ignore the output at this point.

Comment: @ggorlen still meaning that the code has to be sent to a server, something most IT companies would probably not allow.

Comment: @SPArcheon Correct, unless they run the GPT locally or on a company-dedicated private server or something, which is probably prohibitive at present. Also, this sort of feature is already available via CoPilot, I'm pretty sure, although I don't really use CoPilot either.

Comment: @ggorlen when I said "harmless-ish", that's only if it's _not_ dumped on SO as [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/391679/399876) indicates... Also [this](https://github.com/mdn/yari/issues/9208). So I'd better just call it it harmful given the track record of how people actually use GPTs.

Comment: @ggorlen Does it even correctly summarize it? I’d imagine that, especially for such a large amount of text, it mostly just generates something «random» that somewhat fits with parts of the project?

Comment: @AndreasdetestsAIhype I haven't looked at the summaries closely because they're so trivial, but yeah, they probably have the usual hallucinations.

Comment: "This extension pulls in validated content from both the public platform" The word 'validated' by itself here raises so many questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wager it's speaking about the planned feature of the OverflowAI VS Code extension to enable posting AI-generated code explanations to a SOfT or SO.

From [WWC23 - Stack Overflow: Community and AI (Mainstage) at t=25:55](https://www.youtube.com/live/g5F5t205pYA?feature=share&t=1555), at the section where Prashanth is speaking about the explain code feature of the planned VS Code plugin:

> Let's say that you had a piece of code you wanted to really get an explanation for the code and you're able to then do that through this mechanism now. You'll get back sort of a short summary of what you're trying to find out or get an explanation for and you're also going to get references from again our data set on where this explanation really was rooted in, right. So this is a really really powerful way for you again to trust and attribute answers from the public community and within stack overflow for teams, and if you think by the way that this was helpful you can create a Q&A, or you can create an article in this case, it's going to suggest tags automatically and you can post it into stack overflow for teams or public stack overflow.

This is also hinted at in [The SO Labs "Code Editor" page](https://web.archive.org/web/20230727184144/https://stackoverflow.co/labs/code-editor/), but in less detail (does not mention the feature to post to SO, which Prashanth mentioned in his talk):

> - Highlight code to explain the code.
> - Ability to create new questions or articles by creating a draft with tag and title suggestions.
>
> Right now, this will only be available on the Business and Enterprise tier of Stack Overflow for Teams. We’ll explore offering this IDE extension to other tiers in the future.

---

See also: [Will OverflowAI really feature dumping AI code explanations onto Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425787/11107541)

Comment: accepting this answer for now. I'll reconsider in the remove chance that the staff actually post an official statement. I guess you should be pretty safe for the next 6-8 something.