# Annoying voting behavior of some users

Tags: discussion

When asking a question, it's expected that the question shows a minimal research effort. Does this mean the opener just throws in the phrase: "I tried... but it didn't work" without understanding anything?

My concern is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31318256/3110638) which is closed now. The opening poster didn't provide anything he might have tried. When viewing the users history of other questions it showed average votes. For myself I didn't find the question hard to understand. Obviously others did. For these two reasons the questions was massively downvoted and finally closed.

> PCRE **remove characters until alphabetical**... extract just
>   *Yellow Submarine* or *Pop 06 - Yellow Submarine*
>   from the following **set of inputs**...

Especially in the regex tag there are lot's of questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324651/regular-expression-to-pull-data-between-two-nodes-including-nodes), [or this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31308242/3110638) where nothing was tried by OP. Sometimes they even get upvotes.

I found it annoying and arrogant to downvote this question so massively and close it. It is grievous, discouraging and spoils the fun in the forum which I think is most important.

Comment: Related: [Is “too broad” a valid reason to close a question that doesn't show any research effort?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283177/is-too-broad-a-valid-reason-to-close-a-question-that-doesnt-show-any-research)

Comment: *oh, no...it was called a "forum" again*

Comment: I know there has been a lot of different discussions about the regex tag but, in most tags, saying "Do this for me" deserves dvs and cvs, imo. I don't see why the OP couldn't try something found on the internet then post that and say, "This is what I've tried but I'm getting X instead of Y. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?"

Comment: Stack Overflow has its rules. Without wanting to sound like a Soup Nazi, that question was asked entirely the wrong way and comes down to _"Write this RegEx for me"_ without even explaining the logic behind the regex. Such questions are fun for noone, even though some users in the RegEx tag would like you to believe differently.

Comment: I agree, this is exactly what should have happened (with fewer downvotes, of course). It's painful but it teaches a lesson. It's happened to me, too, even with many tens of thousands of reputation points.

Comment: `Especially in the regex tag` Yes because *almost* every regex answer is just: **Your regex ^abc$** and done! I would say out of 100 regex answers, there is at most 1 which explains the regex just a little bit! So the users will never learn how to write their own regex, so the result is just: **I want questions**

Comment: Now that you've called out the other questions the meta effect will likely see them all downvoted equally rapidly.

Comment: @RobertLongson I already asked for removal of my question as I cannot delete it (there is an answer already) Also I will take a break from SO

Comment: @Jonny5 I have rolled back to your original question. You may add some text that you wan't to have it deleted. But such a radical change is rejected. That's at least very disregardful behavior against the answerer. You also might have noticed that downvotes here don't affect your rep.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ All the questions I linked got downvoted since I opened this topic. I didn't mean to harm anyones reputation.

Comment: @Jonny5 They've probably deserved it. THX for (probably unintended) pointing out.

Answer (score 13):

This is absolutely what should happen.  If you want someone to code it for you, go to a freelancer site and pay for it.  The purpose of this site is a forum of last resort for those who can't figure things out on their own.  If the asker had shown even a bad regex that didn't come close he would likely have had a different experience.

Comment: I didn't complain, that the question was actually downvoted - but so massively and closed - in proportion to other similar questions. Well, always coincidence who reads the question.

Comment: It seems like the other questions should have massive downvotes applied too, (to keep it fair).

Comment: Its also the lack of details about this specific question-  he didn't fully define what he wanted out of the regex.  Doing that may be enough to show some effort was put in.  He pretty much put up examples of lines that should hit it.  It reads like a homework assignment.

Comment: @Jonny5: Regex is known as a pit of excrement, rivalling the dreaded [php]. Most sane users completely ignore it, to stay sane. Yes, that means there are too few down-, close- and delete-votes there...

Comment: The original question [is still available here](http://goo.gl/gcqWYR). My concern was about the unfair treatment of exactly this question proportional to similar questions where OP did not try anyting and which sometimes even get upvotes. That the samples which I posted were immediately downvoted reflects the childish behaviour of some users here. There is average of 5-10 such questions each 24 hours in the regex tag. Some of them are indeed interesting.

Comment: I'd still appreciate if some moderator would kindly remove my question here as it leads to nothing good. The only comment that I felt understands what I mean was that of @Pekka웃 *...(with fewer downvotes, of course)*.

Comment: @Jonny5 regarding Deduplicator's comment, he is referring to the tags on SO, not the subjects those tags represent. There is nothing wrong with using regex or PHP specifically, but the questions asked under those tags are generally "piles of excriment". That's just the way it is, there is no need nor any incentive to take it so personal.

Comment: @Jonny5 that's generally the outcome of a site with strict moderation: what you see is what is left over after the crap has been shuffled out!

Comment: @Gimby If the "crap" is shuffled out too fast, interesting questions for future readers get lost. A selection of  SOs most famous "write this regex for me" or theoretical questions of that some would possibly be quickly put to garbage as of now:
[1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/106179/3110638)
[2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5830387/3110638)
[3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/546433/3110638)
[4](http://stackoverflow.com/q/161738/3110638)
[5](http://stackoverflow.com/q/206059/3110638)
[6](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4736/3110638)
[7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/46155/3110638)

Comment: If a question is really crap, of course it should be downvoted. But if a question sounds interesting but is unclear or shows little effort - to ask for providing more details/effort in at least a neutral way.

Comment: I wanted my question here to be deleted as it caused unfairly triggered downvotes in the questions that I linked to and I really did not mean to harm anyone. Deletion was refused because it would be unfair to the community also removing this answer with 13 upvotes. It's yet ~22 unfairly triggered downvotes to the 3 linked questions (including the deleted one) against 13 upvotes for this answer. Unfair because it was triggered and happened unnaturally.