# Why did I fail this review - it's a bad question and should be closed

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I got [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/9804655), and I think this question should be closed, since it is a 'write my code for me' question.

There was no effort (no code sample whatsoever) shown by the person asking it, so I reviewed it as Close > Off topic > "why isn't this code working".

I really think that this question does not belong here. Why did a fail this review audit?

Comment: No, the question was pretty specific about the used technologies, and doesn't seem to ask for code, but what the right operations for alignment would be.

Comment: Why in the world did you select "why isn't this code working" as a close reason?  There is not a piece of code in that question, so why did you think it was an appropriate close reason?

Comment: That question is indeed very unclear. "it" in the two last sentences from that post refer to something, but not to the same thing. After five edits   that post still  has grammar and spelling errors, a strange layout, and punctuation that doesn't really contribute to making it clearer either. Downvote and close as "unclear what you they're asking". What is even more unclear is why that post got any upvotes in its current state.

Comment: "No effort" has not been a valid reason to close for a very long time.  I suspect you failed the audit because you were not paying attention, the one thing an audit checks for.  Or you would have noticed the large number of votes on both the question and the answer, the usual indicator that a community like [ios] considers the Q+A useful.  It is fine to disagree with them, you just won't pass an audit :)

Comment: @psubsee2003 i choose the "why is my code not working" reason, because the OP requested help with some coding. The close reason details what you need to provide for that, and that includes a working example of what was tried so far. That was not provided.

Comment: Wow, 6 downvotes? I came here to learn what i was doing wrong. That's really helpful..

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ you are misusing the close reason.  The key part of that close reason is "why isn't **my** code working".  There is no code, so that close reason is just flat out wrong.  There may be others that apply, but that is clearly not the one.

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ downvoting can be different on meta, so don't take it personally. Voting can be used to express agreement/disagreement.  I can't speak for the downvoters, but I would guess that at least some of the downvotes are because users disagree with your premise that the question in your review is off-topic

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So the easy answer to your question is you failed the audit because you tried to close a question that the community didn't feel needed closing.  The question may be lacking code but seems clear and on-topic.

But to get into more detail, I see 2 problems with your review

First you selected a completely inappropriate close reason.  You should only be using "why isn't this code working" when the user is asking you to debug code without providing sufficient details to highlight the problem.  It is intended for questions like "why is my code not working", with a giant block of code and no indication of where the error is or where it occurs.  It is not for closing questions asking for code and not a default "you are too lazy to do your own work" close reason.

The second part of the problem is you seem to be trying to close a question simply because the OP didn't do enough research in your opinion. There is not a "you are too lazy" close reason, so don't try to invent one.

Not doing enough research is **not** a close reason.  You may choose to downvote such questions because of lack of research (which is perfectly acceptable), but closing an otherwise clear question just because the OP didn't do his/her research is not appropriate.  For the record, I have been on the soapbox before: [Is "too broad" a valid reason to close a question that doesn't show any research effort?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283177/is-too-broad-a-valid-reason-to-close-a-question-that-doesnt-show-any-research/283185#283185)

Comment: Ok, i see. Thanks for explaining this!