# Review audit system needs to be improved

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I fell into the wrong review audit many times because of this. Let me share the details.

[This is the review audit I've encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/23886500)

I read the question and took time and it seems a "too broad" question to me. The user does not explain the proper details. I voted to close it as  **too broad**.

The moderation system shows me a wrong review alert. I don't understand how this question doesn't fall in this category.

If it's a fair question than how we can review such questions?

[image]

One more thing, it is upvoted 11 times, but in review process it does not shows any upvote.

One more evidence, just for reference:

[image]

Comment: That question was chosen as an audit because the system believes it's a "known good" post, because it as 11 upvotes and no downvotes. I notice you haven't chosen to vote on the question either, despite you feeling the question is subpar.

Comment: I am afraid of this kind of post, I was recently put on hold for few days because of this kind of mistake, however you may never know.

Comment: Skip is always a valid choice.

Comment: Review audits lie to you about upvotes to make it less obvious that it is a review. But notice that the question was asked 28 days ago and has 442 views so if it was considered bad it would likely already have been closed. You can always click 'link' to look at the full question with correct votes.

Comment: See also [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307824/why-did-i-fail-this-review-its-a-bad-question-and-should-be-closed), for example.

Comment: @greg-449: Fair point. That was a trap for me.

Comment: I've downvoted this so it won't appear in the close vote queue again. I've also voted to close it (I think you're right).

Comment: @yivi: It happens again with me, I audit and flag this [answer] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38431340/how-to-solve-this-warning-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory/57711098#57711098) as very low quality. Yesterday, it was declined and I was banned for some period. Now the answer you see it is deleted. What's going on?

Comment: No idea, and it’s a different case. I have less than 10k, so I can’t see the deleted answer. If you post a new meta question asking about it; remember using a link to the **review audit** and posting  a screenshot.

Comment: You got that as an _audit_, or flagged it directly? I do not see any recent failed audits in your profile.

Comment: @yivi: Check edited question, attached screenshot.

Comment: If you want to ask about it, post a new question. Your edit introduces things not related to your original question. This was not a review audit, but a regular flag on a post declined by a mod. If you do, you should also provide the screenshot you should for the post, not only from your flag history.

Comment: I know this won't make a difference, actually, I am fade up. I am not going to do any flagging or review from now onwards.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265764/578411 and then you would see that  *just give 755 permission to all file that fine and its work im try it its working for me* **is not** *obvious, unarguable garbage* as a matter of fact, it is an answer but not to the question  asked. Wrong answers need a down vote, not a flag. leave it to 20K-ers to delete those.

Comment: @rene, thanks. This seems helpful. I am waiting for the next privilege.