# "How to Ask" sidebar should mention that 1) googling (or "searchengining") required 2) the code and the problem must be included

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

Currently the "How to Ask" looks this way:

[image]

I'm suggesting to improve the new paragraph in this way:

> First, [***please Google***](http://google.com). Next, provide details, **include the code** in the question (**don't link to external sites unless code provided**) and describe the problem.

[image]

I hope it can convey the problems regarding the questions without code and just links to websites (and also incredible number of duplicates).

Comment: This seem unclear to me.  Do you mean it is OK to provide a link to code in which case say "include or link to code".  Or do you mean only provide a link if you have included code in which case "unless code provided" is redundant.

Comment: I mean second, but I fail to see how "unless code provided" is redutant. You can provide the link only if you've included the code - thats what I was going to express.

Comment: You already said "include the code".  Perhaps" Don't just link to an external site" gives the intended emphasis.

Comment: @David Maybe you're right, but I don't think it's offensive to suggest Googling.

Comment: By “Google” I presume any search engine. I think it’s a bad idea to single out Google in particular.

Comment: I think it should state "Read the manual" as well. Many, many questions can simply be answered by looking at the manual

Comment: Telling people to RTFM, wow - why has that never been tried before?

Comment: You should not encourage people to leave the site. Research is important but look _here at SO_ before resorting to search engines.

Comment: @Matt: These days, the search engine is likely to take the user right back to SO. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Very true. But... with some of the simpler questions that can be solved from documentation (presumably one of those prompted this post) they would end up at something like technet. I prefer your answer in this regard as you reference on site search first.

Answer (score 43):

This is, of course, aimed at the vanishingly-small subset of people who even notice the **How to Ask** sidebar. It's amazing what tunnel-vision people have.

For that small set, I think we need to avoid TL;DR. Also, we don't want to call out Google specifically (there's Duck Duck Go, and Bing, and...). So I'd suggest something like this:

[image]

Note the link to `/help/mcve` (and "on-site search" links to `/search`).

If we wanted to over-engineer (and I don't, see some excellent points in the comments), "on-site search" and "web search engine" could be non-bold links. "on-site search" would put the focus in the search box, copy the title there, and show an arrow pointing at it. "web search engine" would show links that would search on the question title on (say) the top eight search engines. But it seems over-engineered, and as 5gon12eder points out, could suggest that that search alone was sufficient, when of course it isn't.

---

As text:

> **How to Ask**
>
> **Is your question about programming?**
>
> We prefer questions that can be *answered*, not just discussed.
>
> **Search first**, using [on-site search](/search) or a web search engine.
>
> If asking about code, include the **[minimum complete code](/help/mcve)** to demonstrate the issue **in the question** (not just linked!).
>
> Provide details. Share your research.
>
> If your question is about this website, **[ask it on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)** instead.

---

As HTML:

```
<div class="module newuser sidebar-help" id="how-to-title">
<h4>How to Ask</h4>
<p><b>Is your question about programming?</b></p>
<p>We prefer questions that can be <i>answered</i>, not just discussed.</p>
  <p><b>Search first</b>, using <a href="/search">on-site search</a> or a web search engine.</p>
<p>If asking about code, include the <b><a href="/help/mcve">minimum complete code</a></b> to demonstrate the issue <b>in the question</b> (not just linked!).
<p>Provide details. Share your research.</p>
<p>If your question is about this website, <b><a href="http://meta.stackoverflow.com">ask it on meta</a></b> instead.</p>
<p class="ar"><a href="/help">visit the help center »</a><br><a href="/help/how-to-ask">asking help »</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 for letting users choose their search engine

Comment: :-) I was tempted to have a *"Choose one..."* link following that line which would drop-down a list of known search engines, but it seemed over-engineered and contrary to TL;DR.

Comment: I like this version, especially the MCVE link and the search engine neutrality. I wouldn't include the “over engineering links”, however. Not so much because of the over engineering but because it would seem too much like a valid excuse for not trying any other search terms if that suggested query yields no useful results. (And given how descriptive question titles tend to be, it probably would.)

Comment: @5gon12eder: I'm with you, between that and link-overload, they don't pull their weight.

Comment: I concur with Steve, but there'd be nothing wrong with linking `using [on-site search](http://stackoverflow.com/search)`

Comment: @Bergi: Get this: I didn't know about that page! :-) Done.

Comment: I think we should re add the “share your research”.

Comment: @HermannDöppes: Yeah, I removed that in the name of TL;DR, but maybe that's not a good idea. Done.

Answer (score 21):

This sounds like a great idea! Can I make a simple tweak?

> Provide details so we can describe the problem, and **include your code in the question so that we can reproduce it.**

I feel that this creates more emphasis on the fact that by including code, you're helping us help you.

Comment: the only reason to include code is not so readers reproduce it.  a) code cuts thru any language barriers b) provides a clear starting point for any answer esp for XY probs c) for me anyway, it reveals the user's competency level which might impact answers.  I'd prefer: **include code in the question which reproduces or illustrates the problem**

Comment: Right @Plutonix. We don't necessarily want "your code", we want a MCVE.

Comment: (Just saying: edited to include request for googling). The improvements are good, but if I edit them in my question, I'll invalidate your answer.

Answer (score 11):

> #### Only debugging style questions explicitly require code.
>
> I would like to take this chance to correct a common misconception.
>
> If a user has code that doesn't work, and they are asking us why their code doesn't work and how to fix it, they *must* include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example for their question to be on-topic.
>
> Non-debugging style questions are less likely to be too broad or unclear if they do include a code sample (even pseudo code) that demonstrates their intent; but not including a code sample doesn't make the question off-topic by itself.
>
> **If you're closing questions solely because they don't contain code, you're doing it wrong**
>
> <sup>- [What's better: a question with no attempt or with an unfixable/irrelevant attempt?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338755/whats-better-a-question-with-no-attempt-or-with-an-unfixable-irrelevant-attemp/338846#338846)</sup>

I agree that there is a problem with users asking debugging questions and not including an MCVE in the question, and other users asking non-debugging questions that are made off-topic by a lack of code, but I don't think that telling every user we only accept debugging questions is a good solution.

As a member of the [SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chat room, I can attest to the size of the constant incoming tide of garbage; but this is neither the only, nor the most common problem I see with new questions.

**I fear that this suggestion would just create more problems than it would solve.**

One of the biggest problems I see when reviewing in the Close Vote Queue, is users flagging or voting to close reasonable questions as "Too Broad" or "No MCVE" with the reasoning that the question doesn't contain a bunch of noise about what the author tried, thirty links to off-site resources which didn't solve the problem, the background and rationale of the application being developed, and other such meaningless nonsense.

**If it is a clear, well-formulated, and on-topic question that is adequately scoped without code, it may not require code at all.**

**Related:**

- [Is “too broad” a valid reason to close a question that doesn't show any research effort?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283185/4639281)
- [To flag or not to flag question that don't show own effort?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223482/288751)
- [reason for Close: lack of research?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149137/reason-for-close-lack-of-research)
- [Add something about “minimal effort” questions to the “Too broad” close reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224104/288751)
- [Do we need a close reason for zero-effort questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260828/do-we-need-a-close-reason-for-zero-effort-questions)

Comment: You got a point but I think this danger can be mitigated effectively by adding some words like “if you're about to ask for debugging help”. Maybe others can come up with a smarter phrase.

Comment: `the size of the constant incoming tide of garbage` yeh, it requires aspirin to cope with it! :D

Comment: **Some non-debugging questions require code.** But you're right, not all questions require code. I've adjusted the wording in my answer to allow for that.