# Additional close vote reason?

Tags: discussion

One of the most frequent reasons I vote to close a question is if it is a request for code where the user has not made any effort at all.

Would it be helpful to offer that as a reason for closing?

Perhaps as an off-topic - "Stack Overflow is not a place to request code" or something similar?

The reason I am suggesting it is that it may help the original poster understand why their question was closed more quickly, as well as alerting others that they shouldn't bother requesting code.

Comment: You can always leave a comment to further explain exactly why you voted to close, if you feel it's appropriate to help the user understand the site's guidelines.

Comment: Highly relevant: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338846/4639281. Please stop using close votes as super-downvotes and start closing such questions only if an existing reason applies. If you're trying to choose a reason but nothing fits, it probably shouldn't be closed.

Comment: I have sometimes closed homework dumps with a custom close reason - "Voting to close because it is a homework dump that shows ZERO effort from the OP."

Comment: Very related: [Is “too broad” a valid reason to close a question that doesn't show any research effort?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283177/is-too-broad-a-valid-reason-to-close-a-question-that-doesnt-show-any-research)

Comment: Thank you all for the references, answers and comments.  I found them most helpful.

Answer (score 4):

If the user is saying "give me teh codez" without providing any evidence they have tried something, it would be covered under the "Questions seeking debugging help ('why isn't this code working?') must include the desired behavior..." close reason.

If they are asking for links to code that solves their problem, it would be covered by the "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource" close reason.

I don't see the need to have a reason specifically around "not a place to request code" since it's reasonably covered by other reasons that are more specific anyway.

Comment: Your first paragraph is completely wrong.  Reason is that it is confusing.  The user is not asking for debugging help nor have they asked "why isn't this code working", so there is nothing about the close reason that helps them understand the problem with the question.  If it is close worthy, "Unclear what you are asking" and "Too Broad" are much better fits, but even still, asking "how do I do X" without an attempt is **not** off topic.  Suggested reading: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224098/add-something-about-minimal-effort-questions-to-the-too-broad-close-reason/224104#224104

Comment: @psubsee2003 Note Shog9's qualifier there: "But many specific, answerable questions don't include attempted solutions because... There's nothing to attempt: either you know the answer or you don't." There actually _is_ prior effort in some of these questions, the effort of excluding every other factor.

Comment: @S.L.Barth absolutely...  not saying that they are all on-topic, just saying they aren't off topic.  But in general, "How do I do X" isn't off-topic, but other factors in the question might make it close worthy (such as being too broad or unclear)