# too broad a question - deciding on how to fix

Tags: discussion

I have asked a question on SO -
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45731780/calculate-a-cloud-shape-around-several-points-in-space-that-surround-all-of-them and it was put on hold as too broad.

I do want to correct it, but the feedback is not helpful in that respect. From my point of view, the question is very descriptive and very specific on finding a way how to calculate a shape of a cloud around several points in space. The problem domain of the question is very specific and future others could find this math/logic useful.

I would appreciate feedback from the community on how can I make this question more accommodating?

Edit 1-

I delete the question because people started putting trolling comments on it after asking this meta question here, but I put the question here for reference as [I still hold my point](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283177/is-too-broad-a-valid-reason-to-close-a-question-that-doesnt-show-any-research):

> I have nodes drown as points with d3. How do I draw a cloud shape that group those points and surround all of them in one cloud shape?
>
> This is less about d3 and more about the math and algorithm to a function that given a series of points (x,y), output an svg that form a cloud shape that surround all the points.

Comment: Well... a cloud the size of the observable universe would satisfy your question conditions....

Comment: ..or you could bitmap a 'generic' cloud shape, position it at the mean [x,y] of the points, scale it, max[x,y] to the max [x,y] of the points, then multiply by, say, 1.25.

Comment: ..or you could do some research on shape fitting algorithms.

Comment: Cloud itself seem not very well specified (from a mathematical point of view since you are looking for the math behind it).

Comment: Why was my edit on deleting the question because of trolling comments was edited out?

Comment: Because it won't help your argument. And they were more snarky than trolling. They were making actual valid points about your question, which trolls don't actually do. Anyhow, you might want to read these, they can shed some light on why questions like yours aren't seen as acceptable by the community--http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt

Comment: Proper trolling would rather be: "You should ask this question at the [Cloud Computing](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110490/cloud-computing) site instead".

Comment: @elpddev Because there were no trolling comments, only helpful comments helping you with your problem, the comments that you got on your question are irrelevant to your meta question anyway, even if there had been inappropriate comments, and you insulting others and using inflammatory language is not appropriate behavior.  If you're just here to insult people for helping you with your problem, then that's not okay.

Comment: @Servy, I disagree. Trolling is using the opportunity of a conversation to seas the opportunity and insert sarcastic and condescending tone with the alore of an an answer. That not a conversion. Nor do I want suggestions or answers that come with that, nor many other people. The inflammatory language is only found in the troll sarcastic language.

Comment: @elpddev Trolling is deliberately angering someone else for your own entertainment.  Trolling is not giving you an answer to your question, which is what happened here.  That you consider it condescending for someone to give you an answer to your question is...odd...considering you came here to get an answer to your question.  If you don't want to get an answer to your question then why did you ask it in the first place, and why are you here trying to get your question reopened?

Comment: @Servy at this point in time I do not want my question reopened. And as said, so called answers and comments that come with sarcastic and condescending tone, I have no need for nor do I ask for them if that is the price for them.

Answer (score 18):

Spend a bit of time actually trying to solve the problem, rather than just putting the entire specs for what you want to do in an SO question expecting others to do all of your work for you.

If you run into a particular problem while attempting to solve this problem, you do your research into existing solutions to that problem, and you are still unable to resolve it, then you can show what work you've done so far to solve that problem, explain how, specifically, it isn't working, and explain what research you did and how it failed to solve the problem.  Then your problem will have been narrowed down sufficiently as to likely be suitable for the site.

In addition to being too broad, your question is also very unclear.  There are several comments pointing out certain ways in which the question isn't clear, and even beyond what those comments point out the question still doesn't actually provide enough information for it to be answered (recognizing that an answer would *also* be too broad in scope).

Comment: Also going to add, this question would have benefited from (even a hand drawn) diagram of what your expected outcome should look like.