# Triage Queue - Is a new option needed? Too Broad sub-reason?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, triage

I've been working on the Triage queue and think I've found a use case for a new VTC reason: Request for basic instruction" or "Too Basic"

Now, I realize that that's not an appropriate reason to display, but for the purposes of Meta and this question, it gets the idea across.  In particular these questions are of the type "How do I use [Framework]"  with no details or specific problem to be solved.

These are questions that can usually be answered by a single link to a **tutorial** or framework documentation and **shouldn't** be answered here.

"Too Broad" certainly fits, but doesn't provide any real usable feedback to a new user.

Ideally, these questions should be closed with a comment such as:

> This question is a request for basic instruction on a language or framework that is better answered by searching for documentation or tutorials online.  Stack Overflow is designed to provide answers to specific questions with a clear answer. As such, this question is closed. If you need help finding a starting point, try asking in [link to chat]"

Comment: "with no details or specific problem to be solved." Try "Needs details or clarity".

Comment: If the request is for basic information, I wouldn't suggest it's too broad but likely a duplicate of an existing question.

Comment: *"This question is a request for basic instruction on a language or framework that is better answered by searching for documentation or tutorials online. Stackoverflow is designed to provide answers to specific questions with a clear answer."* These two sentences appear to contradict each other, if you want to write a close reason then it needs to be self contained while this is meaningless without your specific example. "Basic instruction" is too ambiguous

Comment: If you don't think the post is well researched, or is unclear, give it a downvote. "This question is a request for basic instruction" is meaningless at best, condescending at worst.  It's also quite subjective, anyone with a grasp of a given language can find the answer with enough docs diving, that doesn't mean it won't be a useful question here.

Comment: the "or tutorials online" bit effectively makes the proposed close reason fit every question ever asked

Comment: If they need an entire tutorial (longer than a reasonable answer), then that's almost certainly a "Needs Details or Clarity" closure; if it's question(s) about a very basic language feature, then (depending on the subject matter), it's very likely a dupe closure. I think our current reasons sufficiently cover the cases you describe.

Comment: Might be a duplicate - [Is "too broad" a valid reason to close a question that doesn't show any research effort?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283177/6045800)

Comment: It's worth pointing out that regardless of whether this is "good" or not - it would need to be better than the existing five site-specific close reasons since SO is already at the max of five.

Comment: methinks such a close reason would lead to broadening the abuse vector (as rightfully pointed out by Kevin B, the definition of "too basic" varies widely depending on the level of knowledge one has about a given topic) without a clear benefit ( answered before -> duplicate; requires a book to answer -> too broad; *extremely* basic misunderstanding of how X works -> typo; not possible to answer *for sure* without clarifications -> needs details or clarity )

Comment: A mandatory reminder, esteemed folks, that "basic" is not a reason to close or delete a post from the network. The platform has been built basically on these rather basic questions and answers, it's just that it reached the state of maturity where it becomes exponentially harder to ask a basic question without it being asked and answered before (and thus are normally justly closed as duplicates).

Comment: @OlegValter what happened to a library of high quality programming questions?

Comment: @Braiam You mean only Questions that no one "just" reading and understanding the documentation can answer? I think they're deleted after being closed as "Primarily Opinion Based".

Comment: @Braiam How does "high-quality" mean "no easy questions"? If it's well-asked (and not a duplicate) even a basic question adds to the value of this site. We're the #1 resource for getting out of Vim and deleting Git branches - we don't want duplicates of those but that doesn't mean that similar "basic" questions have no place here.

Comment: @Catija I'm not saying that, am I? Oleg said and I quote "The platform has been built basically on these rather basic questions and answers". It wasn't. It was built on "high quality programming questions". So, please, stop doing that.

Comment: @Braiam It kinda looks like you are. If that's not the case, perhaps your comment to Oleg needs to be a bit more verbose so that we can truly understand your intentions rather than inferring that you're equating basic questions to low-quality questions (which is how I am currently reading your statement there). Happy to be corrected but feels worth it to point out how your comment is being read (by some at least). :)

Comment: @Braiam nothing, actually - having basic and non-basic questions at the same time constitute a high-quality repository is not self-contradictory. And if you think that, from the start of SO, there only were thesis-like questions, I suggest you are misremembering a couple of things. Here is one (as a nearly random example that took ~10s to look up. I can do this all day) of the oldest JS that lead to help an immense number of devs that is *extremely* basic in nature, yet it is one of the backbones of SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/503093/11407695.

Comment: I think the problem is that they took "a good answer to this question would be too long or has too many possible answers" (or however it was worded) out of the Too Broad/Needs More Focus close reason.

Comment: i mean... a "basic" question as described here wouldn't require an answer that is too long or have too many possible answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reviewing some awful questions is just a waste of time, can we have a "no comment" close reason for these?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261858/reviewing-some-awful-questions-is-just-a-waste-of-time-can-we-have-a-no-commen)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69378552/758133

Answer (score 8):

If it's poorly researched or unclear, downvote it. If it's a duplicate or fits one of the existing reasons, close it. Otherwise... *it probably doesn't need to be closed.*

---

These "basic" questions are often the ones most sought after. They're certainly more useful than the general debugging questions we get every day. Edit it to give it a better title and description/tags so that future users that have it (and dupe hammerers) can find it rather than asking yet another "basic" question.