Should I not flag users with very questionable SG reviews?
Properly reviewing posts in the Staging Ground takes time but sometimes there are users that just approve any question they come across or are closing lots of questions as "Not about programming" or similar when these questions are actually missing details. Reviewing questions like that diminishes the work other reviewers have put into these questions (e.g. if the author didn't understand or address the feedback or only partially addressed it), preventing questions that could be made better by the author from being published (in case of closing questions for missing details like a MCVE) and defeats the purpose of the Staging Ground.
I have raised a custom flag about a user approving many Staging Ground posts (in short succession) where many of these questions shouldn't have been approved. This flag was declined:

This is what their reviews look like which got me to check their individual reviews (these are filtered from the public review history and happened between 2024-10-12 06:58:09Z and 2024-10-12 09:56:09Z).
It started when Karl Knechtel noticed a questionable review which got me to check for other reviews by that reviewer. I found that they approved a lot of questions without looking into these questions at all. Furthermore, the questions they approved had an upvote no matter how bad these questions were so they probably used the "Add an upvote when posted on main site" button on every question. If someone approves and upvotes a question, I would assume they at least read it and like something about it.
The flag was about the following questions:

The question I flagged is obviously not a question to a point and should not have been approved and any reviewing paying at least some attention should have noticed that. It also looks a bit like it could be a spam seed but it was closed on the main site so we'd never know.
This question didn't include what the author expected and what they want ("looks not nice and is a little bit buggy").
This question didn't include any logs and the response was posted as an image of text
This question doesn't specify which part of the issue the author had a problem with/what they tried.
This question was flagged as a dupe before and the user approved it without looking at it
This question is not formatted at all which was also noted in the comments.
This question didn't include how they wanted to use the access key in question, what exactly resulted in the error and didn't provide any logs.
This question doesn't explain what they mean with "putting the code in the text field area" and also didn't include what exactly they expected and where actual_time_needed (and similar) comes from.
This question doesn't include the error they are facing.
This question is not formatted properly (the images were just links that are partially in codeblocks).
This question doesn't include what the author expected/how the actual result is different and it seems they forgot to include the image when writing "here is the image for reference".
This question doesn't include the full error/backtrace they are facing.
This question is missing a MCVE (at least their build configuration should have been included).

I can understand that one can overlook things in question but when a significant amount of approved question has obvious issues that should have been addressed before these questions are posting, it's just not paying any attention to reviews and getting non-questions to the main site. While most individual reviews can be seen as overlooking something, this definitely looks like a pattern and I cannot accept approving this question (especially given that they upvoted it as the other questions they approved) as a proper review.
Do I have too high standards for what I expect reviewers to check before approving questions in the Staging Ground? If so, is it allowed to just approve every question I come across in the Staging Ground no matter how bad it is or where is the line between ok reviews and things that should be flagged (do we first need Community consensus on what a good Staging Ground question looks like)?
Is flagging even the right option for questionable Staging Ground reviews or would it be better to try to communicate with the reviewers by creating a new chatroom or similar?
Or was it my flag description that caused it to be declined? I had to make it short due to the character limit so I couldn't include a proper description on why I think these questions should have not been approved. Should I instead explain the flags like in this MSO post in a private gist or similar and link that from my flag? Is there a recommendation on how to properly flag cases where there are many relevant posts (I use things like [q](/q/<id>) or use a very short text instead of the q for getting many questions into the character limit)?

Technically this one didn't really need the full error traceback as the error message there is very distinctive. I'd agree though that the review was bad since if the error message appears so specific I'd expect at least a quick search for duplicates (And it is a duplicate since that error message is somewhat common).

Regarding duplicates, I don't think we can expect reviewers searching for duplicates as that can require subject-matter expertise and requires quite some work that reviewers aren't informed about having to do.

"This question doesn't include the error they are facing." and the reviewer even commented "Providing the error message or output sample helps quickly identify the problem and solution" and then approved 11 seconds after posting the comment.

Good catch. But I have no idea what their intention approving (and likely upvoting, the approved post has one upvote and one downvote) was after writing that comment. Maybe they didn't understand what the approve option is actually doing and what it means?

I'm more interested if that spur of reviews was driven by the new widget and/or badge that focuses on number of reviews did.

I also fear that this wouldn't get better with reputation incentives which are solely focused on approved questions...

Side quesstion, I don't see the "filter by user" button from your screenshot; how do you enable that?

@ThomA I wrote a user script for that.

Of course it's not built in functionality... Why would it be. >_<

I think that moderators have tooling for that but I don't know what the mod tooling for it looks like.

I've flagged users with questionable (non-SG) review behavior (taking 3-10 seconds per review) and got rejected/declined. I'm not doing that again any time soon.

Yes, I agree that this is something requiring input from moderators. That being said, I think it should be clear what we should do and don't (for example if my flag description was the issue, it would be good to know about a preferred way of informing mods about these issues), what is considered abuse in terms of reviewing and I want to know whether I should continue flagging which is why I created this MSO post.

There seem to be a handful of users who do almost all approvals, despite most other actions being spread across many more users. This seems to subvert the point of staging ground. There should be a limit on the number of individual actions one can take, not just the total. E.g. max 10 approvals, 10 off-topic etc. See here for the prevalence of robo approvers: https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/review-history?page=2&reviewAction=ApproveAndPublish

In general, I think you should still flag it if you see reviewers with problematic behavior. Regarding reviewers doing approvals, it seems like around 104-110 (3.75-4%) reviewers are doing 50% of approvals and 511 (18.4%) reviewers are doing 80% of approvals if my code/calculations are correct (but note that this includes reviewers who only reviewed a single question etc). (state: all approvals up to 17.10. at some time so it includes the betas).

To answer the general question: yes, do flag users that may be robo-reviewing in any queue. Review audits are not always enough to catch robo-reviewers; a moderator is needed to inspect the review tasks and impose review suspensions as needed.
(As a matter of fact, other flags reporting possible robo-reviewers you made were marked helpful.)
About the case at hand however, I had a look at the links you provided and at a bunch of other recent reviews from that user and frankly, while I agree they made several mistakes, I didn't get a strong impression they were robo-reviewing, i.e. clicking through tasks without even thinking. They did skip some reviews, indicating the user is aware they can "Skip" reviews.
For Staging Ground, moderators can also see how long the user took to review each task1. The time this user took to review each task seemed somewhat reasonable.
For some of the reviews you noted, as well as some others I checked, it seems the more correct action would've been "conditionally approve with minor edits" or "duplicate". Should these kind of mis-review be treated the same as deleting a code-only post in Low Quality Answers? We don't review-suspend users for failing to identify dupes in Triage either.
Staging Ground is a new review queue on Stack Overflow. I feel we, moderators but perhaps the community as a whole too, haven't yet set the bar for what is considered a so poor performance to be worthy of a review ban. Therefore, in my opinion, the sensible approach is to handle these reports conservatively in favor of the reviewer.
Also, I'd advise against counting the number of non-approvals to sustain an allegation of robo-reviewing. There might be correlation, but not necessarily causation.
Perhaps I could've marked the flag "helpful" to signal that reports like this are appreciated.

1: this UX is very helpful and really should be extended to other queues

"Perhaps I could've marked the flag "helpful" to signal that reports like this are appreciated."  Declining flags tells the flagger that they should not  have flagged.  Unless the user had the information to know that the flag was not helpful, you should always mark as helpful as it allows you to use your information to make that decision.  Also, "review-suspend" is not the only possible action that you could take.  "Hey, a lot of your reviews have mistakes, please watch out for ..." is a reasonable message to send to a bad reviewer.

Perhaps this is a feature miss.  Maybe flags should be markable as helpful, accepted, or declined.  Then you wouldn't have to mark acceptable flags as helpful or declined.  Perhaps "message the reviewer" should be a systemic action rather than something that you do manually.

@mdfst13 it’s not possible to message a user about reviews without review-suspending them. It’s possible to send them a profile-level warning, but I strongly disagree with conflating site-wide behavior with poor reviews.

In cases where it looks like the reviewer has good intentions and might not understand some options, do you think it's a good idea to contact the reviewer in chat or similar?

@dan1st mmm, I don't think it's very scalable. If the user builds up enough objectively harmful reviews, then a moderator might reach out via the appropriate channels. I just don't think we got to that point yet for this particular user.

"Perhaps I could've marked the flag "helpful" to signal that reports like this are appreciated." - at the least, it might be a good idea to tighten the bolts on the documented best practices, which I hope exist, among moderators about when to mark something helpful. A flag not being acted upon is not a hard "no", that's for sure.

I don't believe  quality control of staging ground reviews  should be included in moderators scope of work. Flags shouldn't be used for this purpose, unless the user approved obvious spam or rude/abusive questions repeatedly to prove there's a pattern.
There is a lack of quality control in staging grounds, which are present in other review queues.  This should be dealt only by the company using

Audit reviews similar to suggestions queue and/or
Voting: Currently, the approval and denial votes are not balanced as one approval vote overides multiple denial votes. There's a lack of consensus here.

Having said all that, even if nothing more is implemented, there are regular close vote reviews, after posting. Do we flag users who repeatedly vote to reopen questions, which we believe are unfit for site or users who repeatedly vote to close questions which we believe are really well researched? Flagging shouldn't be used for quality control.

In my experience, flags that notify moderators about reviewers with a series of wrong reviews in the Low Quality queues are handled by them. I don't think a single review warrants a flag, but there are often people who abuse reviews. The last terrible reviewer I noticed left 20 link only votes (in LQP) in 5 minutes, most on posts without links. How else would we stop them?

"Do we flag users who repeatedly vote to reopen questions, which we believe are unfit for site" yes, assuming you find such a user. And also their reopen votes should be blatantly wrong, not just disagreement. But yes, you can vote such cases. Same with the close votes. Again, they have to be blatantly wrong. Not just a few simple mistakes in a large body or disagreement on what is closeable (when it's clear different people might have different opinion). Clear patterns of wrong review actions are definitely flaggable.

"I don't believe quality control of staging ground reviews should be included in moderators scope of work" - who else should do it with the current system? // "Audit reviews similar to suggestions queue" - audits have many issues // "Currently, the approval and denial votes are not balanced" - there aren't really denial votes. The most important Staging Ground action is "Requires Major Changes" which can be done single-handedly and in case there is a dispute over questions, that should IMO not be handled in the SG anyways because the SG isn't made for disagreeing reviewers.

I have many flags (including recent ones) where I've flagged robo-reviewers and they have been both marked as helpful and the users stop reviewing/submitting suggested edits (either due to education or suspensions from the action). I don't see why SG reviews should be different. If moderators lack the tools to action such tasks, then that doesn't make them "not helpful"; the problem then is the tooling (which we know is bad anyway).

@ThomA the moderators have at least tooling to see reviews of individual users in SG (without a script like the one dan1st is using) and to ban / suspend them from SG (A mod had mentioned this in chat somewhere). So that wouldn't be the reason to decline such flags.

@ThomA Robo reviewing is obviously crossing a line. But I don't see any such issues with OP's post.

@VLAZ who decides what's blatantly wrong? As said in my answer, Spam or rude/abusive... yes.. sure. But, most if not all of what  OP said is debatable.

@TheMaster if you can't decide what's blatantly wrong, feel free to not raise flags for such behaviour.

Yes, lets introduce audits because they're working so well for all the other review queues.

@KevinB Maybe we should remove audit from all other queues and just ask users to flag for moderator attention eh?

or maybe... not attract people to reviews who aren't going to take it seriously and instead are using it to chase badges/clout.

If someone is voting to reopen obviously terrible questions, I would absolutely flag them, I don't know about you.

@Starship The problem is terms like  "obviously terrible" and "blatantly wrong" are subjective. What's terrible to me maybe acceptable to you and excellent to someone else. Isn't that why consensus exist in the first place? Moderators are  and should be exception handlers -when there's a really rare exception that the community couldn't handle on it's own. I would argue coming to meta is much more fruitful rather  flagging, as it at least shows consensus.

Umm...okay how's this. If a post should be closed, then you shouldn't vote to reopen it. If a user has a pattern of voting to reopen questions that should be closed (which is not subjective, do they meet the closure criteria), then a flag is reasonable (particularly if you suspect some form of robo-reviewing). @TheMaster

@Starship Robo reviewing, Yes, I agree with flagging. But, the rest, meh... Every close reason is more or less subjective.  Also, let's turn the tables a little ...Do we also need to flag close voters who VTC using the reason "Needs more focus/too broad" as a proxy for "no research effort"(when it is not to be done https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283185 )? I know for a fact it is still done blatantly and if I were to flag, I have to keep on flagging every day.

@TheMaster Okay, walk me through that. For example, I think its quite objective whether or not an asker included a minimal reproducable examples. I think its objective if a questions asks for off-site resources. I think it's objective if a question asks a lot of different questions in 1. If you want to flag that, then you're welcome to, see if your flag is accepted or not...

I don't agree with all close reasons being generally subjective. While there are cases for all close reasons with the decision of some specific question falling under the criteria being subjective, this doesn't mean that the close reasons are generally subjective. For example, "not about programming" or "not written in English" are objective concepts and there are questions that should objectively closed under these reasons (but there are still some questions where that decision is subjective, especially if the question is right on the line of that close reason).

@dan1st  Practically, most close reasons are used subjectively. Majority of community members don't want that question, due to valid reasons or otherwise(like a rude user, or if they're tired of seeing too many questions) and therefore decide to close it. The actual reasons are framed after the decision to close it. While I agree,  that close reasons become objective in cases, like where the question is fully in another language or if the issue is clearly caused by a typo, or if the issue is clearly not reproducible,  they're more of an exception than the rule.

@dan1st Even in your quoted cases "Not about programming", I see questions regularly being closed, which I clearly disagree with. Ultimately, it's  just about what the majority or the organized minority(SOCVR) thinks. There's no clear rhyme or reason to this. If you have the manpower to back it up, you can make any question offtopic and even delete it.

abuse of close privileges is a valid reason to raise a flag, even if there's a chance you might be wrong. there's no reason that can't also hold true for reviews, whether in SG or other queues. that said, in some of these cases it might be better to start a meta discussion about a given question (not the user who took an action)
